# Code golf - сортировка символов строки по алфавиту

Tags: любой-язык, соревнование

Задание: написать функцию (метод) который будет принимать строку и возвращать ее рассортированную по алфавиту, игнорируя регистр.

- К примеру если передать `сТрока` то она должна вернуть `акорсТ`.
- Строка, передаваемая в вашу функцию может быть как на английском, так и русском языке, но не комбинированной обоими. **Причем строки с буквой Ё тоже должны правильно сортироваться**.

  > апХчиЕмаЁ -> ааЕЁимпХч
- Предполагается что будет передаваться лишь строка из букв и ничего более (ни цифр, ни знаков препинания, ничего, кроме букв)

Условия: участники могут отвечать на разных языках, публикуя такие решения в разных ответах. Победителем станет тот, кто напишет ее за меньшее количество символов, структура ответа - язык, в скобках количество символов, сам код, ссылка на проверку.

Победитель получит 500 репутации, поехали!
Итоги проведутся через 3 дня (статус конкурса откроется, ответ победителя отмечу верным)

---

<sub>Пожалуйста, указывайте в ответе количество символов, чтобы проще было выявить победителя.</sub>

```js
function getAnswers(questionId, answer_filter, page) {
  return jQuery.ajax({
    url: '//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/' + questionId + '/answers?page=' + page + '&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=activity&site=ru.stackoverflow&filter=' + answer_filter,
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true
  }).then(function(data) {
    if (data.has_more) {

      return getAnswers(questionId, answer_filter, page + 1).then(function(d) {
        return data.items.concat(d.items);
      })
    }
    return data.items;
  });
}

function getAuthorName(e) {
  return e.owner.display_name
}

function process(items) {

  return items.map(function(item) {
    var matched = item.body.match(/(\d+)[^\d]*?<\/h/);
    if (matched) {
      return {
        count: +matched[1],
        link: item.share_link,
        author: getAuthorName(item)

      };
    } else {
      return {
        count: 'N/A',
        link: item.share_link,
        author: getAuthorName(item)
      }
    }
  });
}

function sort(items) {
  return items.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.count == 'N/A') return 1;
    if (b.count == 'N/A') return -1;
    return a.count - b.count;
  })
}

function fillTemplate(sortedItems) {
  $('#leadership').append(sortedItems.map(function(item, index) {
    return $('<tr>').append($('<td>').html(index + 1))
      .append($('<td>').html(item.author))
      .append($('<td>').html(item.count))
      .append($('<td>').append($('<a>').attr('href', item.link).text('Link')));
  }));
  return sortedItems;
}

var QUESTION_ID = 671346,
  ANSWER_FILTER = "!4*SyY(4Kifo3Mz*lT",
  startPage = 1;
getAnswers(QUESTION_ID, ANSWER_FILTER, startPage)
  .then(process)
  .then(sort)
  .then(fillTemplate);
```

```css
#leadership {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#leadership td,
#leadership th {
  padding: 5px;
}
#leadership th,
td:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Таблица лидеров</h1>
<table id="leadership">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Автор</th>
    <th>Количество символов</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59834/discussion-on-question-by-flippy-code-golf-----).

Comment: Гольф не актуален?

Comment: @Anatol, угу. Читайте коммент Mike. Я сейчас кое чттюо поинтереснее делаю )

Comment: Может тогда добавить эту информацию в заголовок?

Comment: Народ, вы сумасшедшие... В хорошем смысле слова))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Pyth (<s>17</s> 16)

```
DhZRo:rN0\ё"ее"Z
```

[Проверка](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=DhZRo%3ArN0%22%D1%91%22%22%D0%B5%D0%B5%22Z%0Ah%22%D0%9F%D0%BE+%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83+%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB+%D1%91%D0%B6+%D0%B8+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4+%D0%91%D0%9E%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D1%83%D1%8E+%D0%81%D0%9B%D0%9A%D0%A3%0A&debug=0)

Расшифровка. pyth стековый язык, поэтому параметры немного не там, где вы возможно привыкли их видеть...

```
DhZ  Объявить функцию h(Z)
R    возвращающая (return)
o    сортировка с помощью лямбда-функции "labda N:"
:    строковая замена (из стека)
rN0  переводим букву параметр лямбды(N) в нижний регистр, кладем в стек
"ё"  кладем в стек второй параметр замены - "что меняем"
"ее" и третий - "На что меняем"
Z    помещаем в стек входную строку для "o"
```

Comment: Вот доказательство бессмысленности сравнения длин результатов для разных языков

Comment: @br3t Конечно. Но ведь подобные вопросы code-golf в общем то не для этого. Это позволяет узнать много нового. отточить знания по знакомым языкам, освоить новые.

Comment: Очуметь, я чаем поперхнулся!

Answer (score 12):

## Elisp (<s>102</s> <s>91</s> 102)

Чисто ради экзотики:

```
(defun f(s)(defun c(a)(if(eq(upcase a) ?Ё)(+ ?Е 0.5)(upcase a)))(seq-sort(lambda(a b)(<(c a)(c b)))s))
```

С `Ё` сортирует правильно теперь.

Для работы требуется пакет `seq` `(require 'seq)`. Ниже есть ответы, где такая подготовка не учитывается в количестве символов, поправьте, если надо добавить.

Проверка (может занять некоторое время):

```js
function check() {
  var cmd = "#!/bin/sh\ntmpfile=$(mktemp); echo \"(require 'seq)(defun f(s)(defun c(a)(if(eq(upcase a) ?Ё)(+ ?Е 0.5)(upcase a)))(seq-sort(lambda(a b)(<(c a)(c b)))s))(print (f \\\"" + $("#src").val() + "\\\"))\" > $tmpfile;emacs --script $tmpfile;rm $tmpfile;"
  $("#cmd").val(cmd)
  $("#cmd").runPark($("#bd"), function(data) {
    $("#bd").html("<p>Результат: " + data["stdout"] + "<\p>")
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//eval.dan.co.jp/jquery-runpark.js"></script>
<div>
  Введите слово: <input type="text" id="src">
  <input type="hidden" id="cmd">
  <input type="submit" value="Отсортировать" onclick="check()">
  <div id="bd">
  </div>
```

Код проверки:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmpfile=$(mktemp); 
echo "(require 'seq)(defun f(s)(defun c(a)(if(eq(upcase a) ?Ё)(+ ?Е 0.5)(upcase a)))(seq-sort(lambda(a b)(<(c a)(c b)))s))(print (f \"<введенное слово>\"))" > $tmpfile;
emacs --script $tmpfile;
rm $tmpfile;
```

Comment: Упс, забыл обратно соединить строку, сейчас поправлю

Comment: Укоротить не получится? :D

Comment: А если прям представить что у вас ограниченная память XD

Comment: @Flippy да, на свежую голову удалось отыграть 11 символов :D

Comment: А работает ли ваш код со строкой "МиномЁт"? Буквы ё (йо) там где надо?

Comment: что-то строка `провркаЕеФааА` выдает ответ `аааАвЕекопррФ`,  хотя заглавная буква `А` должна быть впереди....... с `ТестоваяСтрока` и буквой `C` - аналогично

Comment: @АлексейШиманский почему? я как-то проглядел, где написано про то, что заглавные должны идти перед строчными. Если я не ошибаюсь, речь не шла о том, что есть какая-то сортировка по регистрам.

Comment: @Flowneee я возможно ошибся. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/671346/code-golf-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83/671598#comment976691_671377  .......поэтому уточняющий комментарий по поводу этого я оставил под вопросом ТС ....

Answer (score 11):

## Python (43)

```
f=lambda s:''.join(sorted(s,key=str.lower))
```

[Проверка](http://ideone.com/YyBlWH)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59833/discussion-on-answer-by-maxu-code-golf-----).

Comment: апХчиЕмаЁ => ааЕимпХчЁ неверно же

Answer (score 10):

## Wolfram Mathematica (<s>35</s> <s>45</s> <s>38</s> 34)

<s>g[s_]:=StringJoin@Sort@Characters@s</s>

<s>z[s_]:=StringJoin@AlphabeticSort@Characters@s</s>

<s>z[s_]:=Row@AlphabeticSort@Characters@s</s>

```
z=Row@AlphabeticSort@Characters@#&
```

Онлайн проверку не смог запилить, поэтому скрином:

[image: Скриншот тестов]

<s>P.S. Не работает, русские буквы неверно сортирует с учетом регистра</s>

Comment: Для `qqqQQQqQqQ` разве не должно было вернуть то же самое?

Comment: @br3t по условию не запрещалось менять местами порядок символов, лишь бы регистр не влиял

Answer (score 9):

## Javascript ES6, 48 символлов

```
s=>[...s].sort((a,b)=>a.localeCompare(b)).join``
```

Проверка:

```js
f=s=>[...s].sort((a,b)=>a.localeCompare(b)).join``
console.log(f("еёЁжикЕст"))
console.log(f("МиномЁт"))
```

Comment: А работает ли ваш код со строкой "МиномЁт"? Буквы ё (йо) там где надо?

Comment: @Flippy, да, добавил. Давай-ка ты лучше полный список тестов в вопрос?)

Comment: Господи, жс это монстр

Comment: Уже добавил) ))

Comment: @Flippy, тесты добавил? Не вижу.

Comment: У меня сломался мозг и я не смог это в вопросе описать, представляете?

Comment: о, вот и норм ответ по js. К стыду своему про localeCompare я не знал =)

Comment: `м` и `М` в последнем тесте переставились же

Comment: @br3t главное `Ё`  на месте! :)

Comment: . кстати неправильно работает... должно быть `EеЁёжикст` судя по требованиям ТС в каком-то комментарии :D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, насколько я понимаю, равные буквы могут идти в любом порядке.

Answer (score 8):

## C# (53)

```
var a=string.Concat(s.Select(c=>""+c).OrderBy(x=>x));
```

http://ideone.com/yIfq3W

---

P.S. Как я понял из под комментария под вопросом: одинаковые буквы но с разным регистром могут идти в любой последовательности. Если так, то я сократил код до представленного выше до тех пор, пока не опровергнется утверждение. В ином случае верну предыдущий вариант. Ждем-с комментарии ТС.

Comment: [Работает](http://ideone.com/vBzGcj) :)

Comment: @Qwertiy конечно работает. Он ж сравнивает чары как строки длиной 1. Поэтому даже StringComparison в виде CurrentCulture не нужно применять. Но всё вариант тупой и ужасный. Попробую что-то получше потом

Comment: А работает ли ваш код со строкой "МиномЁт"? Буквы ё (йо) там где надо?

Comment: @Flippy смотря что означает `Буквы ё (йо) там где надо?`

Comment: Между Е и Ж, как в алфавите ;)

Comment: @Flippy ну дык а где ж её еще быть? Можешь сам на ideone проверить)

Comment: Воооо!! Молодец) а укоротить никак?

Comment: @Flippy цитирую себя из коммента выше: `всё вариант тупой и ужасный. Попробую что-то получше потом` )

Comment: @Flippy, а чем `МиномЁт` отличается от `еёЁжикЕст`?

Comment: Ну блин, вы меня запутали) просто придает внимание букве ё

Comment: `.ToCharArray()` вроде как можно опустить :)

Comment: @AGS17 точно.спасибо.

Comment: `string s(string x) => new string(x.OrderBy(char.ToUpper).ToArray());` Сортирует всё, кроме буквы `Ё`.

Comment: @VladD спасибо. жаль она должна быть)

Comment: @Flippy сократил код в разы пока не будет нормальное уточнение по тому, как реально на выходе может быть выглядеть исходная строка.. (читай комменты под вопросом)

Comment: `var a=` не нужно

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript(ES6) (163)

```
s=>s.split('').sort((x,y)=>{return x.toLowerCase().replace('ё','е'+String.fromCharCode(1110))>y.toLowerCase().replace('ё','е'+String.fromCharCode(1110))}).join('');
```

***Если учитываем русские буквы, то должны учитывать букву `ё`***

Проверка:

```js
let a=s=>s.split('').sort((x,y)=>{return x.toLowerCase().replace('ё','е'+String.fromCharCode(1110))>y.toLowerCase().replace('ё','е'+String.fromCharCode(1110))}).join('');

    console.log(a('строка'));
    console.log(a('AaZ'));
    console.log(a('ёапрст'));
```

Comment: Можете ссылку на проверку кода прикрепить?

Comment: во-первых точку с запятой можно опустить, во вторых два символа в начале Вы утаили, в третьих я уже это писал в комментарии =)

Comment: точку с запятой и правда лишняя) в задании сказано что нужно написать функцию, а не функцию вместе с переменной куда эта функция будет присваиваться для вызова, то что вы написали - это не ответ

Comment: не подойдет если в строке будут буквы разных регистров

Comment: регистр на выходе должен остаться неизменным

Comment: Автор, ваш код не является методом. + регистр букв должен игнорироваться, тоесть если передать `AaZ` то должно вернуть `AaZ`, а не `AZa`

Comment: @Flippy почему это не функция(метод)? на счет регистра, сейчас исправлю

Comment: Ой, насчет функции ошибся ;)

Comment: И добавьте ещё тест для `ТестоваяСтрока`, пожалуйста

Comment: `ТестоваяСтрока` выдает что-то смешное))

Answer (score 6):

## Perl  (42)

```
sub f{join'',sort{lc$a cmp lc$b}pop=~/./g}
```

Для корректной работы с русским языком в скрипте должны быть включены прагмы

```
use utf8;
use locale;
```

[Проверка](http://ideone.com/eS2vAw)

```
sub f {                   # Объявление функции
  join  '',               # Собрать из массива строку, разделяя элементы пустой строкой
   sort {                 # Сортировка массива
          lc $a cmp lc $b # Функция сортировки, сравнивает буквы (cmp)
                          # В нижнем регистре (lc).
                          # $a и $b предопределенные переменные для сортировки
        }
    pop                   # Взять параметр функции из массива параметров
        =~ /./g           # и сравнить с регулярным выражением "один символ"
                          # с флагом "g" (глобально) в списковом контексте (данным sort)
                          # возвращает массив совпадений, т.е. отдельных символов
}
```

Comment: Можете ссылку на проверку кода прикрепить?

Comment: Пока что вы лидер :) Я сейчас пробовал на Java написать, но не вышло никак минимум 80. Наверное, час напролет гуглил)

Comment: И решил просто для количества написать на руби. Хотя я его не знаю, но все же написал  :) наверное укоротить можно, но я не хочу

Comment: При попытке запустить с русским - http://ideone.com/1qnD5f - не получил ничего. Или я что-то сделал не так?...

Comment: @Harry, строка не может быть комбинированной :)

Comment: А работает ли ваш код со строкой "МиномЁт"? Буквы ё (йо) там где надо?

Comment: @Mike, копипаст всем, про вас забыл)

Comment: @Mike, не учитывается) просто подпишите что "если подключить это, то..."

Comment: @Flippy Кстати, на счет питона, и подозреваю, что и руби то же, это воплне может зависеть от настроек локали в системе. т.е. если в переменных окружения сказано, что локаль русская, то тот же скрипт начинает работать корректно. конечно это надо проверить. только на ideone боюсь не выйдет ...

Comment: Вообщем, надо Perl учить, крутой язык)

Comment: судя по [комментарию ТС](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/671346/code-golf-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83/671598#comment975966_671371) - тут немного неверная последоватльность. при одинаковости букв, но различающихся по регистру - заглавная должна идти в начале

Comment: @Flippy ↑  может в вопросе это укажешь тоже?

Comment: я возможно ошибся. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/671346/code-golf-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83/671598#comment976691_671377  .......поэтому уточняющий комментарий по поводу этого я оставил под вопросом ТС ....

Answer (score 6):

## C# (73)

```
string s(string x)=>new string(x.OrderBy(c=>(""+c).ToUpper()).ToArray());
```

Вроде бы более короткий вариант.

http://ideone.com/SNpqGc

Comment: `ТестоваяСтрокаПроверкиНаВшивость` - не сработало .........`TestMePleaseAndCryLouuUdd` - аналогично

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: У меня `аааввВвееииккНооооПрррсСсТтттшья`, а как надо?

Comment: Обратите внимание на `в` и `с`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: Ну вроде ж так и надо? Одинаковые символы перемещаются, сохраняя относительный порядок, разве не это нужно? Надо уточнить у ТС.

Comment: мммм....... как мне казалось https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/671346/code-golf-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83/671598#comment976691_671377:  при одинаковости букв, но различающихся по регистру - заглавная должна идти в начале....... может я неверно понял его коммент

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: Я так понял [этот комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/671346/671598#comment975966_671371), что `AaZ` не превращается в `AZa`, т. к. `A` и `a` должны считаться одной и той же буквой.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: Подождём объяснений ТС.

Comment: Да. Уже написал под его вопросом комментарий) Но уже, если честно, ничего не хочется) Соревнование и  вопрос явно сырой

Answer (score 5):

## C++ (90)

```
auto g(string s){sort(begin(s),end(s));return s;}
```

[Проверка](http://ideone.com/QXBiik)

Да, упустил из виду нечувствительность к регистру... Так, конечно, длиннее - пока 90 символов.

```
auto g(string s){sort(begin(s),end(s),[](char a, char b){return (a|32)<(b|32);});return s;}
```

http://ideone.com/8P4wbV

Comment: Не знал что в C++ так просто это сделать, а пробел между `s.begin()` и `s.end()` вы не написали чтобы символов меньше было?)

Comment: Ой, вы вообще ванлайн сделали :D неплохой результат в самом начале))

Comment: А почему не `auto` вместо `string` в начале? Это ж минус 2 символа.  :)

Comment: @Flowneee Спасибо, принимаю :) Если заработаю 500 баллов - 20 ваши :)

Comment: Используя лямбда-функцию и 14 стандарт можно ещё сэкономить: `[](auto s){sort(begin(s),end(s));return s;}`

Comment: @retorta Думал о лямбдах. Но ее нужно сохранить - еще как минимум 7 символов, и потом, это уже формально шаблон функции :), который не только для строк работает. Поэтому не решился. И потом, после присваивания нужна точка с запятой - так что те же 49 символов: `auto g=[](auto s){sort(begin(s),end(s));return s;};`

Comment: Ваш метод учитывает регистр) нужно чтобы сортировка происходила без его учета, тоесть `АаZ` должен вернуть `AaZ` а не `AZa`

Comment: @Flippy Да, не заметил. Тогда сразу 90 символов, если не придумаю покороче :) Да, как понимать ваше замечание о "хоть английский, хоть русский"? Я могу ограничиться английским? Потому как сразу же встанут вопросы о локали, интернационализации, кодировке (а вдруг UTF-8 требуется?) и иже с ними...

Comment: @Harry, нет, метод должен принимать как английский так и русский, оба должны работать

Comment: Кандидат на победу изначально были :D

Comment: Неужели на плюсах это будет длинно?

Comment: @Flippy Все, при этом условии схожу с дистанции - потому что проверить не удастся :) - ideone - сами гляньте - при русском языке начинает чудить. Мой код при установке `setlocale(LC_ALL,"RUS");` на VC++2015 даст сортировку, но русские буквы в ней будут идти раньше английских. На ideone не будет выдано ничего вообще (проверьте, кстати, любое приведенное решение с русскими буквами на ideone...). И что засчитывать? :) Кстати, не критики для, но в порядке размышлений - фактически тут идет не соревнование программистов, а соревнование языков.

Comment: @Harry Картинку в посте приведите, как в вольфраме, что у вас с вашей локалью работает и все :) Вообще думаю большинство языков при правильных настройках системы то же будут работать корректно. У меня вот perl на ideone без `use utf8` то же вообще ничего не выдавал, а у меня на машине и без этого отлично работает.

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript ES6 (163)

Проблема с `ё` решена.

```js
s=t=>{l=q=>{q=2*q.toLowerCase().charCodeAt();return q==2210?q-55:q};r={},d='';[...t].forEach(i=>{(r[l(i)])?r[l(i)]+=i:r[l(i)]=i});for(var j in r){d+=r[j]}return d}

console.log('Tests:');
['AaZbBXo', 'ТестоваяСтрока', 'ЁлкаёлочкА', 'МиномЁт'].forEach(function(testStr) {
  console.log(testStr + ' => ' + s(testStr));
});
```

**Правка**: из-за нестабильности работы `sort` пришлось пойти немного другим путем, через числовые ключи объекта.

Comment: А работает ли ваш код со строкой "МиномЁт"? Буквы ё (йо) там где надо?

Comment: Поправил.......

Answer (score 5):

## PHP 7.3 (<s>263</s> 258)

```
function s($s){$a=array_filter(preg_split('//u',$s));$u=function($s){return ($r=unpack('V',iconv('UTF-8','UCS-4LE',mb_strtolower($s)))[1])==1105?1077.5:$r;};usort($a,function($a,$b)use($u){return $u($a)<$u($b)?-1:$u($a)==$u($b)?0:1;});return implode('',$a);}
```

<s>[Проверка](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2f13a5caaed844e9b910e7a4720268a01c940a4f)</s>
[Проверка](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/804b6eadaa288aa20b55d7c4e03188216a5417b3)

Получение кода символа в UTF-8 на основе этого [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27444149/2486051).

Comment: `ТестоваяСтрокаПроверкиНаВшивость`  - не прошла) что-то с порядком буквы `с`  ............ у строки `ПочемуВсёТАКСложносБуквойС` - всё сложно с `к` :D  .............и тут `aabdeeeFIIiimmnNnooorrssSTtt` ....... беда)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, регистр букв не учитывался в общем, я подумаю, что сделать можно, не превращая функцию в еще большего монстра.

Comment: я возможно ошибся. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/671346/code-golf-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83/671598#comment976691_671377  .......поэтому уточняющий комментарий по поводу этого я оставил под вопросом ТС ....

Comment: В общем да, я подошибся https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/671346/code-golf-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83/671598#comment976898_671346  ........в итоге я свой код на основе коммента сократил втрое :)

Answer (score 5):

## psql / Postgres (99 b)

```sql
\set v '\'привеЕтЁ\''
SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(v ORDER BY v),'')FROM(SELECT REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(:v,''))AS D(v);
```

Чисто в копилку :-)

Comment: Кстати, автору  Perl-кода рекомендую все-таки `use feature 'fc' - http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fc.html.

Хотя для данного golf это и неважно, но писать лучше правильно.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby (3, или 24, или 72)

```rb
class String;def d;downcase.tr('ё','е');end;end

def g(s)
s.chars.sort_by(&:d).join
end

p g("еМиномЁтЙ")
```

http://ideone.com/yZytxP

можно изменить код так, что вызов будет

```rb
def g s
s.g
end
```

http://ideone.com/ZiSxGK

Answer (score 5):

## Crystal (3, или 24, или 75)

```rb
struct Char;def d;x=downcase;x=='ё'?'е': x;end;end

def g(s)
s.chars.sort_by(&.d).join
end

p g("еМиномЁтЙ")
```

https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/25jk

можно изменить код так, что вызов будет

```rb
def g(s)
s.g
end
```

https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/25jr

Answer (score 4):

## Scala (113)

```
  def m(p:String)=p
                   .toCharArray
                   .map(_+"")
                   .sortWith(Collator.getInstance(new Locale("RU")).compare(_, _)<0)
                   .mkString
```

[Проверка](http://ideone.com/Qj1WZA)

Answer (score 3):

### F# (146)

```
List.sortWith(fun a b->String.Compare(a,b,true,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))((List.ofSeq s)
        |>List.map(fun x->Convert.ToString(x)))
        |>String.Concat
```

https://ideone.com/agogSy

В отличие от C#, CultureInfo надо задавать явно... А так бы вышло покороче (34):

```
s.OrderBy(fun a->a)|>String.Concat
```

Answer (score 3):

### Kotlin (70)

```
s.split("").sortedWith(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER).joinToString("")
```

http://ideone.com/ySMgZE

Увы, не работает с "Ё". Решил всё равно запостить, так как автор [сам постил такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/671431/183842). Может кто дополнит в комментариях, как победить эту "Ё".

Answer (score 3):

### T-SQL (195)

```
DECLARE @l INT=LEN(@s)-1DECLARE @t TABLE(c NCHAR(1))WHILE @l>=0BEGIN INSERT INTO @t(c)SELECT SUBSTRING(@s,LEN(@s)-@l,1)SET @l-=1 END SELECT(SELECT c AS[text()]FROM @t ORDER BY c FOR XML PATH(''))
```

Для SQL Server 2014. В 2016 сделали `SPLIT_STRING`, но сам не пробовал ещё.
Проверить онлайн не знаю где, [SQLFiddle вроде как сломан](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35735405/4269118).

Answer (score 3):

## Perl6 (35) не работает Ё

```
sub f{[~] $^x.split("").sort(*.lc)}
```

Сортирует без учёта локали, возможно найду способ, тогда обновлю.

[Проверка](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/7@4NEkhrTq6LlZBJa5Cr7ggJ7NEQ0lJU684v6jEqlovJ7m21lohTUPpwoYL@y8svdh@YceFqRf2AHmNIEWJlf//f83L101OTM5IBQA)

Comment: *Сортирует без учёта локали, возможно найду способ* -
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/671377/183842

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby (48)

```
def g(s)
return s.chars.sort(&:casecmp).join
end
```

Не работает с Ё

[Проверка](http://ideone.com/Y0XH73)

Comment: http://ideone.com/zI2IET - с русским не работает

Comment: @Harry, строки с комбинированными языками не будут передаваться в метод, или ru или en но никак не ru+en

Comment: Не работает... у тебя у самого ответ `aaafFfWX` ....... заметь `fFf`

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, ох черт :')

Answer (score 0):

## PHP 7.4 (89)

[Collator](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.collator)

```php
function s($s){$a=mb_str_split($s);(new Collator('ru_RU'))->sort($a);return join('',$a);}
```

[Проверка](https://onlinephp.io/c/25fd4)