# Код-гольф: Увеличиваем цифры

Tags: любой-язык, соревнование

**Задача**: Написать код минимально возможной длины, выводящий полученную на вход, строку из цифр большим, символьным шрифтом. Шрифт должен быть в точности такой, как указан тут, в вопросе.

**Пример**:

На вход получена строка "0123456789", на стандартный вывод программа должна вывести:

```
  ###      #     #####   #####  #       #######  #####  #######  #####   #####
 #   #    ##    #     # #     # #    #  #       #     # #    #  #     # #     #
#     #  # #          #       # #    #  #       #           #   #     # #     #
#     #    #     #####   #####  #    #  ######  ######     #     #####   ######
#     #    #    #             # #######       # #     #   #     #     #       #
 #   #     #    #       #     #      #  #     # #     #   #     #     # #     #
  ###    #####  #######  #####       #   #####   #####    #      #####   #####
```

**Правила и ограничения**:

- Программа может, но не обязана быть оформленной в виде функции. Если    она функция - синтаксис объявления этой функции (`int main() {}` для C)    не учитывается в размере, важен размер самого рабочего кода.
- Входная строка может поступать в программу любым, удобным вам, способом: в виде переменной, указанной в тестовом примере непосредственно перед кодом, в виде параметра функции или со стандартного ввода.
- Входная строка может содержать только цифры
- Результат должен быть выведен на стандартный вывод в текстовом виде. Если стандартный вывод направлен на терминал, экран считать достаточной ширины для вывода всего контрольного примера c запасом. Переход на новую строку обозначайте (явно или не явно) любым символом/комбинацией символов, использующейся для перевода строки на вашей платформе (Например, `\n` или `\r\n`).
- Шрифт результата должен в точности соответствовать указанному выше. Между цифрами на выводе должен быть минимум один пробел (цифры не должны сливаться). Шрифт считается моноширинным, т.е. вокруг единицы может быть больше пустого пространства т.к. ее изображение ýже остальных цифр.
- В программе *запрещено* использовать любые встроенные в язык и библиотеки к нему функции сжатия и кодирования данных (Такие как: zip/unzip, base64)
- Программа должна содержать шрифт (или код его формирующий) непосредственно в своем теле. Получать шрифт из внешних источников (ввод, диск, сеть, память видеоадаптера, bios) *запрещено*.
- Размер программы учитывается в байтах. Побеждает программа имеющая минимальный размер

---

**Конкурс окончен**

Первое место занимает @RusArt с [ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/677391) на 05AB1E, длиной всего 91 "байт".

Втрое место занимает @Anton Petrusevich с [ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/674753) на perl, длиной 150 байт.

И третье место достается @retorta с [ответом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/674471) на python, длиной 161 байт.

В ответах рассмотрены самые разные способы сжатия шрифта. При подготовке к конкурсу я рассматривал большинство из них. Самым простым для реализации и в то же время достаточно эффективным оказалось сжатие до 70 байт в 7 битной, горизонтальной, кодировке (оригинальное моя кодировка представлена в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/675325) на postgresql. Даже удалось попасть в диапазон допустимых символов, поменяв 6-7 биты и вычтя 2. Правда не все участники заморачивались и тратили драгоценные байты на кодирование в диапазон печатных символов с 0x20 до 0x7E. Применяли кодирование как есть, часто с 8 битом или залезая вообще в диапазон управляющих. В принципе такое кодирование имеет право на жизнь, программы на той платформе, где писались работают. Хотя мне и не очень нравится когда программу нельзя напечатать на принтере, ввести по новой с листа и что бы при этом она продолжила работать (Вы не сможете опубликовать свой код в книге ;) ).

Победителем была использована совершенно другая кодировка шрифта. Словарь из 16 возможных 7и символьных элементов шрифта (в битовом кодировании) и кодовая таблица с номерами частей для каждого символа, которая благодаря нестандартной кодовой странице языка 05AB1E заняла 35 "байт" (технически в этом языке используются 256 графем, которые принято считать "байтами" потому что их именно 256 и если бы реально существовала такая кодовая таблица, то их все действительно можно было бы закодировать одним байтом). К сожалению подобное кодирование в других языках невозможно в принципе, в связи с тем, что из 256 значений байта в кодировке ASCII 31 используется для управляющих кодов, а 128 старших значений плохо переносятся между платформами.

Подобный подход со словарем в принципе был использован еще в нескольких ответах, но там не применялось бинарное кодирование в результате чего шрифт занимает гораздо больше места. В процессе подготовки конкурса я рассматривал даже несколько вариантов кодирования со словарем. Например, две комбинации `#####` и `#     #`, встречающиеся очень часто, предполагалось кодировать двумя битами со значениями 10 и 11, а остальные варианты 5и битным значением, первый бит которого 0, что бы отличить от первых двух и остальные 4 бита номер варианта. На практике же это давало совсем небольшой выигрыш в кодировании шрифта и при этом код декодирования оказывался слишком сложным и в код-гольфе неприменимым и опять же в обычном ascii коде уложить это очень сложно.

В ответах можно найти и совершенно иные способы кодирования, например, кодирование повторов `#` и пробелов просто количествами подряд, представленном в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/674440) @Qwertiy

К сожалению никто из участников не пробовал использовать вертикальное кодирование, т.е. где элементом выступает 7 бит кодируемого символа берущихся из него по вертикали. А при таком способе кодирования получается очень много повторов. Присмотритесь к цифрам 5689 у них отличаются только 1 и последняя вертикаль, остальные одинаковы. При кодировании повторов в такой строке удается достичь практически такого же сжатия как и в случае с словарем и битовым кодированием. Но на практике гольфа опять же слабо применимое из за роста объема декодирующего [кода](http://ideone.com/RocTRR).

---

**Альтернативный рейтинг**

К сожалению не удалось сформулировать правила так, что бы они действительно отражали то, чего я хотел от конкурса. Во многих ответах используются символы не работающие в другой кодировке символов или функции близкие по смыслу к base64, т.е. представляющие закодированную строку как одно большое число, в результате чего в коде отсутствует собственноручное ее декодирование. В данном альтернативном рейтинге я отражаю результаты, как бы они выглядели, если бы правила были точно сформулированы.

1. Anton Petrusevich, [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/674753) на perl, длиной 150 байт
2. Андрей, [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/675849) на C#, длиной 176 байт
3. Visman, [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/674829) на PHP, длиной 235 байт

---

<sub>Пожалуйста, указывайте в ответе количество байт, чтобы проще было выявить победителя.</sub>

```js
execute("ru.stackoverflow.com", "674415");
```

```css
.cssload-container,.cssload-cube{width:97px;height:97px;transform-style:preserve-3d}.cssload-container,.cssload-cube,.cssload-half1,.cssload-half2{transform-style:preserve-3d}.cssload-container{position:relative;margin:23px 84px;perspective:292px}.cssload-cube{animation:cube 11.5s forwards infinite;transform-origin:center 49px}.cssload-half1,.cssload-s1{top:0;transform-origin:50% 100%}.cssload-half1{height:39px;position:absolute;animation:half-fold 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-side{width:19px;height:19px;background:#ddd;position:absolute}.cssload-s1{left:39px;animation:s1ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s2,.cssload-s3,.cssload-s4{left:39px;transform-origin:50% 0}.cssload-s2{top:19px;animation:s2ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s3{top:39px;animation:s3ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s4{top:58px;animation:s4ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s5{left:19px;top:19px;transform-origin:100% 50%;animation:s5ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s6{left:58px;top:39px;transform-origin:0 50%;animation:s6ani 11.5s forwards infinite}@keyframes cube{0%,30%{transform:rotateX(0)}40%{transform:rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0) rotate(45deg)}60%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotateY(0) rotate(45deg)}65%,70%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotate(45deg) rotate(180deg)}75%,80%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotate(45deg) rotate(1turn)}90%{transform:rotateX(0) rotate(0) rotate(0)}}@keyframes s1ani{0%{opacity:1;transform:translateY(0);background:#ddd}40%{transform:rotateX(0);background:#ddd}50%{transform:rotateX(-90deg);background:#ddd}90%{transform:rotateX(-90deg)}}@keyframes s2ani{0%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}10%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{background:#ddd}45%,80%{background:#b4b4b4}65%{opacity:1;background:#b4b4b4}90%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s3ani{0%,10%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}20%,90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{background:#ddd}45%{background:#969696}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s4ani{0%,20%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}10%,to{opacity:0}30%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{transform:rotateX(0);background:#ddd}50%{transform:rotateX(90deg);background:#b4b4b4}80%{background:#b4b4b4}90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(90deg)}}@keyframes s5ani{0%,10%{opacity:0;transform:rotateY(-179deg)}20%{opacity:1;background:#ddd;transform:rotateY(0)}40%{transform:rotateY(0)}50%{transform:rotateY(90deg)}55%{background:#ddd}60%{background:#c8c8c8}90%{transform:rotateY(90deg);opacity:1}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s6ani{0%,20%{opacity:0;transform:rotateY(179deg)}30%{opacity:1;transform:rotateY(0)}40%{transform:rotateY(0)}50%{transform:rotateY(-90deg);background:#ddd}60%,80%{background:#c8c8c8}90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateY(-90deg)}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes half-fold{0%,50%{transform:rotateX(0)}60%,90%{transform:rotateX(-90deg)}}
```

```html
<script src="https://mayorovp.github.io/codegolf/table-8c505e68f1349e4c69e7.js"></script>
<div class=cssload-container><div class=cssload-cube><div class=cssload-half1><div class="cssload-side cssload-s1"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s2"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s5"></div></div><div class=cssload-half2><div class="cssload-side cssload-s3"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s4"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s6"></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: А почему в таблице нет языка и рейтинга? Вот тут лежит есть доработанная: https://mayorovp.github.io/codegolf/

Comment: @PavelMayorov Я скопировал из последнего активного вопроса по теме. сейчас эту попробую

Comment: Когда кончается соревнование?

Comment: @Eanmos Этого пока не решил, думаю не меньше недели, в чате обсужу ...

Comment: не понял про то, что экран считать достаточным по ширине, но при этом использовать что-то для переноса строк?

Comment: @teran, ну должно быть выведено 7 строк из которых состоят символы. Имеется в виду, что не надо никакие переносы всего текста ставить дополнительно.

Comment: @teran Это пересраховка. Изначально я хотел написать просто "на стандартный вывод", потом в чате начали задавать вопросы, что если экран слишком узкий и не влезет. В итоге немного заумным языком имеется ввиду "не морочьте себе этим голову, просто выводите текст, если не влезает, возьмите терминал по больше"

Comment: @Mike: Интересно, входная строка именно в этой последовательности и количестве, или в любой и в любом, главное чтобы из чисел?

Comment: @TimurVI Любая последовательность из цифр. Количество такое, что бы на экран после распечатки умещалась

Comment: "Лишние" пробелы возле 1 принадлежат самой 1?

Comment: @br3t Да, она то же 7 символов в ширину. НО согласно правилу "_Между цифрами на выводе должен быть минимум один пробел_" вы можете сделать ее уже, главное что бы один пробел зазора остался. Но даже 10 пробелов зазора нарушением не будет. И думаю сжимать ее в шрифте особо не стоит, код обработки исключения ширины наверно больше места займет (мне так кажется, смотрю на ответы с массивами и думаю, что это не всегда так :) )

Comment: @Mike, мне кажется, не надо разрешать подрезать единицу. А расстояния должны быть одинаковыми.

Comment: @Qwertiy Подрезание единицы особо не помогает сокращать код. И что то менять в условиях уже мягко говоря поздно

Comment: @Mike, так в условиях это всегда было: _"Шрифт считается моноширинным"_

Comment: Кто нибудь мне обьяснит, что это за код в конце вопроса и что с ним делать?

Comment: @Flippy Нажать "показать код", и потом на появившуюся кнопку "выполнить код". Он покажет текущие результаты конкурса

Comment: @Mike, ага) только вот на моб. версии нет их

Comment: Я конечно дико извиняюсь :), но в этом ответе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/674698 куча непечатных символов. Парсер сайта пропустил только 47 или 49 из 70. Остальные не могут быть верно отображены :Р

Comment: @Visman Проглядел ... пойду следующие искать ... :)

Comment: @Visman Ха, следующим оказался как раз ваш ответ. Потому как на kotlin (который на 2 байта меньше) использован перевод всей строки в другую систему счисления как единого числа

Comment: Сделал гадость и на сердце радость :)

Comment: помимо 5689 средние вертикали еще такие же у 2,3 и поменьше для 0.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## 05AB1E, <s>-78</s> <s>91</s> 86 bytes

```
7F"‰ʒØTs“c7н7ƒÔΛ`"255öb7ô"KƶΘåé©¨ÈÐjη½ñ4BØ„ZĆ¤™Ωë₄´Ø#Ã.Dι¯ƒ“T"255öhIS7*N+èHè)»1'#‡0' ‡
```

[Попробовать](https://tio.run/##AaUAWv8wNWFiMWX//zdGIuKAsMqSw5hUc@KAnGM30L03xpLDlM6bYCIyNTXDtmI3w7QiS8a2zpjDpcOpwqnCqMOIw5BqzrfCvcOxNELDmOKAnlrEhsKk4oSizqnDq@KChMK0w5gjw4MuRM65wq/GkuKAnFQiMjU1w7ZoSVM3Kk4rw6hIw6gpwrsxJyPigKEwJyDigKH//zAxMjM0NTY3ODn1bm8tY2FjaGU)

Словарь в 255-й системе счисления:

```
 ‰ʒØTs“c7н7ƒÔΛ`
```

При преобразовании в двоичную и разделении на группы по 7 получаем это:

```
['1000001', '0011100', '0100010', '0001000', '0011000', '0101000', '0111110', '0000001', '1000000', '1111111', '1000010', '0000010', '1111110', '0000100', '0010000', '0111111']
```

Сам шрифт кодируется в 16-й системе счисления (в словаре 16 элементов)

```
1200021 3453336 6076889 6076709 8AAA9BB 988C706 608C006 9AD3EEE 6006006 600F706
```

В программе он также переведен в 255-ю систему счисления:

```
KƶΘåé©¨ÈÐjη½ñ4BØ„ZĆ¤™Ωë₄´Ø#Ã.Dι¯ƒ“T
```

Прогоняется цикл от 0 до 6, в каждой итерации ввод пользователя преобразуется в индексы шрифта, которые в свою очередь восстанавливаются по словарю. В конце программа все собирает и заменяет 0 на пробел и 1 на #.

**UPD**
Заменил использование `•` на явное преобразование системы счисления.

> ö  = pop a,b    push int(a, b)

**UPD** 
Исправил цифру 3, заодно самоликвидировался костыль и код получился меньше

**Расшифровка**

```
 7 - кладем в стек число 7
 F - берем из стека число a, в интервале от 0 до a выполняем следующие команды
 "‰ʒØTs“c7н7ƒÔΛ`" - кладем в стек строку
 255 - кладем в стек число 255
 ö - берем из стека a и b, выполняем преобразование системы счисления числа a с основания b к основанию 10, кладем результат в стек
 b - берем из стека число, преобразуем число в двоичную систему счисления, кладем результат в стек
 7 - кладем в стек число 7
 ô - берем из стека a и b, делим a на группы по b элементов, кладем в стек массив
 "KƶΘåé©¨ÈÐjη½ñ4BØ„ZĆ¤™Ωë₄´Ø#Ã.Dι¯ƒ“T" - кладем в стек строку
 255 - кладем в стек число 255
 ö - берем из стека a и b, выполняем преобразование системы счисления числа a с основания b к основанию 10, кладем результат в стек
 h - берем из стека число, переводим его в 16-ю систему счисления
 I - кладем в стек пользовательский ввод
 S - берем из стека строку и кладем массив ее символов
 7 - кладем в стек число 7
 * - берем из стека a и b, умножаем, кладем в стек результат. Тут массив умножается на число, то есть каждый элемент массива умножается на число
 N - кладем в стек текущий итератор из команды F (2-я по счету, N = [0..6])
 + - берем из стека a и b, складываем, кладем в стек результат
 è - берем из стека a и b (a - шрифт, b - индекс), кладем в стек a[b] (код из словаря)
 H - переводим число из 16-й системы в 10-ю
 è - берем из стека a и b (a - словарь, b - индекс), кладем в стек a[b] (часть рисунка) 
 ) - тут играет роль end F
 » - на этот момент в стеке есть строки с частями рисунка, команда соединяет их в одну и вставляет между ними перенос на новую строку
 1 - кладем в стек число 1
 '# -  кладем в стек символ #
 ‡ - берем из стека a,b,c (a - рисунок, b - 1, c - #), в a заменяем b на с
 0 - кладем в стек число 0
 '  -  кладем в стек пробел
 ‡ - берем из стека a,b,c (a - рисунок, b - 0, c - пробел), в a заменяем b на с    
 в конце программа сама выводит на экран последний элемент стека (наш рисунок)
```

Comment: Посмотрел на язык внимательнее, ok, их байты будем считать байтами, потому как их используется не более 256, просто в общепринятой кодировке их графемы приходится кодировать по другому. Но `•` переводит систему счисления сразу строки, работая с ней как с массивом, что относится к функциям кодирования данных. Максимум что можно применять - это перевод системы счисления одного символа или одной числовой переменной в программе.

Comment: @Mike могу вместо `•` использовать побитовое преобразование, код получится немного длиннее. Так засчитается?

Comment: Если вы при этом сами побайтно пройдете строку циклом или например map, то да.

Comment: А можете расшифровку написать, на подобии такой https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/671747  С учетом очень слабой документации на golf-языки подобные расшифровки очень полезны для обучения

Comment: как мне кажется, на этом гольф можно закрывать

Comment: @Mike, код работает неправильно - тройка выводится не таким шрифтом что в условии

Comment: @RusArt Действительно, что у вас с 3 случилось ?

Comment: @Mike, Все, исправил

Comment: У вас в коде скрытая реклама [N+èHè](http://nehe.gamedev.net/)

Comment: @pank Надо же)))

Answer (score 17):

## Python3, 161 байт

```
def f(s):
    for i in'0123456':print(*(format(b'>>@>>>"AAB@ABAAA(B@@AAA>>B~~>?A@AA"@AAAAA>>>>>>'[int(i+j)],'7b').translate({48:' ',49:'#'})for j in s))
```

SO режет некоторые символы, так что код скопированный отсюда не будет работать, но если скопировать [отсюда](http://ideone.com/hRQVPC), то всё работает.
[Проверка](http://ideone.com/hRQVPC)

Comment: Длина в байтах (не в символах) - какая?

Comment: Хм. почему 338. я скопировал в файл, выкинул строку с def (согласно условию про объявление функции), убрал по 1 пробелу в остальных строках (т.к. они выравнивание под def) получил 290

Comment: Тут символов намного меньше чем байт :)

Comment: @Visman я понимаю, я копировал в UTF8, проверил в дампе, символы остались многобайтными

Comment: @Mike, https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxhiz.png - 284 байта в UTF8 без BOM.

Comment: Хм, да. Пока я, кажется, насчитываю у себя больше, чем на самом деле.

Comment: @retorta пишите 284, у нас с qwertiy почти сошлось :) Хотя мне после копирования проверить не удалось, python орет `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character ` видимо надо как то переменные окружения выставить

Comment: @Mike, он уже код поменял)

Comment: @Mike Может быть вы использовали второй питон? Там нет такой из коробки поддержки юникода. Он как раз выдаст примерно такую ошибку.

Comment: @retorta Точно ! я думал у меня по умолчанию 3й в системе, а оказалось 2й

Comment: Если я пытаюсь скопировать код отсюда, то он у меня не работает, а когда копирую с ideone, то работает. Похоже, тут сломали кодировку)

Comment: @andreymal В этой строке есть немножко непечатных символов. SO их просто удаляет, а ideone --нет.

Comment: Теперь, когда я пытаюсь скопировать из ideone сразу в интерпретатор, он тупо закрывается ._. Пришлось предварительно сохранить в файл)

Comment: С непечатными символами спорное решение. от редакторов зависит. у меня например скопировать даже из ideone через putty не выходит. он все восьмибитное пытается к UTF привести и разумеется у него это не выходит. в итоге код выглядит как тут. с другой стороны никаких правил по поводу этого я не вводил. Ну хоть как то достигли 70 байтного шрифта и то хорошо

Comment: А байты надо снова пересчитать под ideone...

Comment: @Qwertiy вроде теперь с размером проще. Сейчас все используемые символы однобайтовые.

Comment: @retorta, с ideone скачивается файл размером 227. Или кодировку укажи, какая нужна?

Comment: @Qwertiy По ссылке файл больше, так как там ещё заголовок функции и пример запуска, которые не учитываются. Вот минималистичный [код](http://ideone.com/9LIZYv). Он скачивается, как 184 байта.

Comment: Надо переписать на pyth.

Answer (score 15):

## Perl, <s>230</s> <s>165</s> <s>155</s> <s>153</s> 150 символов и байт.

Вся программа в ASCII, поэтому, число байт, занимамых программой, равно числу символов. Символы шрифта кодированы простой формулой, чтобы оставались печатными.

```
$_="0987654321";
for$l(0..6){say map{sprintf("%08b",127&(80+ord substr'L8nnp/n/nnRHqqrpqrqqqX11rpp4qqq8nnr..8noq8p1/1q@q1R8pq2qq@qqLn/n2nn@nn',$l.$_))=~y/01/ #/r}/./g}
```

Ideone: https://ideone.com/gbBuzn

Комментарий: код эволюционировал, приведён последний вариант. С подсказками Mike. Можно ужать ещё, наверное, пару символов, если формулу взять подсказанную, но тогда совсем моего авторства не останется :)

Update: минус ещё два символа за счёт того, что `ord` берёт код первого символа строки. Спасибо Alexander Onokhov.

Update: минус ещё три символа за счёт переупорядочивания данных шрифта и замены умножения на слияние строк. Идея "Someone Unknown".

Comment: @AntonPetrusevich, `Уже локти кусаю, что не написал в правилах, что скрипт не должен содержать непечатных в UTF8 символов (включая, кстати, управляющие). Хотя я подумывал вообще запретить байты с установленным 8 битом, но подумал что слишком жестко – Mike` Ни кто правила конкурса не нарушает!

Comment: @Visman А он и не говорит, что вы нарушаете, он пишет, что вы "хитрые" :)

Comment: Даже к 70 символам понадобится декодер. Сходу как не увеличить декодер я алгоритма не увидел, поэтому для "неподходящих" символов ввёл префикс. Впрочем, может быть я ещё раз подумаю что сделать, чтобы остаться в пределах ASCII. "Лишние" символы вырезаются оператором подстановки.

Comment: Я начал с того, что записал в явном "печатном" виде строку шрифта, где непечатные символы были записаны явно как "\x04" и т.п., строка вышла 140 символов, зато никакого декодера не надо. Заменить непечатные на печатные но с префиксом обошлось в 53 символа, но сэкономило 70 при этом.

Comment: Добавил вариант с 70 символами на шрифт, формула моя собственная :)

Comment: Да, спасибо, сейчас переоформлю.

Comment: Если воспользоваться "хитрым" способом, то можно получить 132 символа. Но, пусть автор того способа сам выступит :)

Comment: Мне все покоя не давал константный цикл по строкам. http://ideone.com/scR4NY к сожалению размер не улучшает, если не ухудшает, но может натолкнет кого на какие идеи еще :)

Comment: Да, интересная мысль. Я тоже никак не могу придумать что сделать вместо `for$l(0..6)`.

Answer (score 12):

## Javascript ES6, <s>376</s> 286 символов

Входные данные в переменной `s`.

```
`235145251167151715251
1131323152524111615241115251
151111191624111615051215251
15131452511411616414526
15131316068625121415161
01131413161515111525121415251
0233517156125253155251`.replace(/./g,(m,i)=>' #'[i&1].repeat(m)).split`
`.map(x=>s.replace(/./g,i=>x.substr(7*i,7)+" ")).join`
`
```

## Проверка:

```js
f = s => `235145251167151715251
1131323152524111615241115251
151111191624111615051215251
15131452511411616414526
15131316068625121415161
01131413161515111525121415251
0233517156125253155251`.replace(/./g,(m,i)=>' #'[i&1].repeat(m)).split`
`.map(x=>s.replace(/./g,i=>x.substr(7*i,7)+" ")).join`
`

document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input", function (e) {
  document.querySelector("pre").textContent = f(e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, ''));
})
```

```css
body { display:inline-block; }
input { position:sticky; left:8px; width:calc(100vw - 16px); box-sizing:border-box; }
```

```html
<input>
<pre></pre>
```

### Старая версия (376 символов)

Внимнание! Первая строка кода заканчивается пробелом!!!

```js
f = s => ` 2#3 5# 4#5 2#5 # 6#7 #5 #7 #5 2#5 
 # 3# 3#2 3# 5#2 5#2 4# # 6# 5#2 4# # 5#2 5#
# 5# # # 9# 6#2 4# # 6#  9# 2# 5#2 5#
# 5# 3# 4#5 2#5 # 4# #6 #6 4# 4#5 2#6
# 5# 3# 3# 6 6#8 6#2 5# 2# 4# 5# 6#
 # 3# 4# 3# 6# 5# 5# # 5#2 5# 2# 4# 5#2 5#
 2#3 3#5 #7 #5 6# 2#5 2#5 3# 5#5 2#5 `.replace(/.\d/g,m=>m[0].repeat(m[1])).split`
`.map(x=>s.replace(/./g,i=>x.substr(7*i,7)+" ")).join`
`

document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input", function (e) {
  document.querySelector("pre").textContent = f(e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, ''));
})
```

```css
body { display:inline-block; }
input { position:sticky; left:8px; width:calc(100vw - 16px); box-sizing:border-box; }
```

```html
<input>
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: я тут вообще ничего не понимаю :D

Comment: а не, понимаю (:

Comment: Вы бы его как нибудь развили, что ли ... Я пока вопрос готовил пробовал кодировать просто "2354" первая цифра пробел вторая диез и т.д. остается только развернуть в строку, думаю какой нибудь выбор по четности текущей позиции будет в самый раз

Comment: @Mike, надо подумать на эту тему. На первый взгляд мешают ```  9``` и ``` 6 6``` :)

Comment: @Qwertiy Не понял на счет " 6 6#", это же вроде как "7 6#". А если где то число превысит 9 - то выхода 2, использовать шестнадцетиричку (ее хватает) или например разбивать 11 диезов подряд как "506", под 0 имеется ввиду конечно пробелы

Comment: @Mike, точно, нолик))) Не подумал про него. Там числа 10 и 12.

Comment: @Mike, пожал)))

Answer (score 10):

## Javascript, 376 символов

```js
function printn(n) {
var r=Array(7),s,i,d,k=0;while(n[k]){d='ab222ba7c777711231445123132148885dd546332112462215ef799912212211220321'.substr(n.split('')[k]*7, 7).split('');for(i=0;i<7;i++){s=' ######, ##### ,#     #,      #,#      ,#######,###### ,   #   ,#    # ,  #    ,  ###  , #   # ,  ##   ,     # ,#    # ,    #  '.split(',')[parseInt(d[i],16)];r[i]=r[i]?r[i]+' '+s:s}k++}return r.join('\n');
}

// Test
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input", function (e) {
  document.querySelector("pre").textContent = printn(e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, ''));
});
document.querySelector("pre").textContent = printn('0123456789');
```

```css
body { display:inline-block; }
input { position:sticky; left:8px; width:calc(100vw - 16px); box-sizing:border-box; }
```

```html
<input value="0123456789" />
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: О, вы пошли через вариант со словарем ... у вас сложно шестнадцатиричное в десятичное переводить ? Если нет, можете закодировать варианты с 0 и в hex тогда точки с запятой не понадобятся

Comment: Да, как раз планировал, спасибо.

Answer (score 8):

## PHP7.0, <s>211</s> <s>189</s> 182 символов

@Mike уточнил в комментарии, что base64_decode() под запретом. <s>Это тот же вариант на 252 символа,</s> но строка со шрифтом представлена символами ASCII с кодами от 0 до 254, а функция base64_decode() удалена. Код не может быть нормально отображен в кодировке UTF-8

```
<?php
function p($s) {
for($l=-1;$l++<6;){foreach(str_split($s)as$y)printf('%8s',strtr(decbin(ord("8||��|�||D0���������P������||���|~���� �D���� ��8|�||| ||"{$l*10+$y})),'01',' #'));echo"\n";}
}
p('0123456789876543210');
```

Чтобы получить рабочий файл используйте код генерации

```
<?php
$a = '38107C7C80FE7CFE7C7C443082828480828482828250020284808008828282107C7C84FCFC107C7E82108002FE028220820244108082048282208282387CFE7C047C7C207C7C';
$b = '';
for($i=0;$i<70;++$i){
    $b .= chr(hexdec(substr($a,$i*2,2)));
}
file_put_contents('test.php', "<?php
function p(\$s) {
for(\$l=-1;\$l++<6;){foreach(str_split(\$s)as\$y)printf('%8s',strtr(decbin(ord(\"$b\"{\$l*10+\$y})),'01',' #'));echo\"\\n\";}
}
p('01234567890123456789');
");
```

## PHP, 252 символа

```
<?php
function p($s) {
    $a = base64_decode('OBB8fID+fP58fEQwgoKEgIKEgoKCUAIChICACIKCghB8fIT8/BB8foIQgAL+AoIgggJEEICCBIKCIIKCOHz+fAR8fCB8fA==');
    for($l=0;$l<7;++$l){
        for($i=0;isset($s{$i});++$i){
            printf('%8s', str_replace(['0','1'], [' ','#'], decbin(ord($a{$l*10+$s{$i}}))));
        }
        echo"\n";
    }
}
p('98765432101');
```

Сжатый вид (252 байт)

```
$a=base64_decode('OBB8fID+fP58fEQwgoKEgIKEgoKCUAIChICACIKCghB8fIT8/BB8foIQgAL+AoIgggJEEICCBIKCIIKCOHz+fAR8fCB8fA==');for($l=0;$l<7;++$l){for($i=0;isset($s{$i});++$i)printf('%8s',str_replace(['0','1'],[' ','#'],decbin(ord($a{$l*10+$s{$i}}))));echo"\n";}
```

Тест http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2f683e07299be492ac6b1af758ea7bab37ef3eba

## PHP, 292 символа

Читабельный вид

```
<?php
function p($s) {
    $a = '38107C7C80FE7CFE7C7C443082828480828482828250020284808008828282107C7C84FCFC107C7E82108002FE028220820244108082048282208282387CFE7C047C7C207C7C';
    for($l=0;$l<7;++$l){
        for($i=0;$i<strlen($s);++$i){
            printf('%8s', str_replace(['0','1'], [' ','#'], base_convert(substr($a,$l*20+$s{$i}*2,2), 16, 2)));
        }
        echo"\n";
    }
}
p('987654321054');
```

Сжатый вид (292 байта)

```
for($l=0;$l<7;++$l){for($i=0;$i<strlen($s);++$i)printf('%8s',str_replace(['0','1'],[' ','#'],base_convert(substr('38107C7C80FE7CFE7C7C443082828480828482828250020284808008828282107C7C84FCFC107C7E82108002FE028220820244108082048282208282387CFE7C047C7C207C7C',$l*20+$s{$i}*2,2),16,2)));echo"\n";}
```

Тест http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8f895964dd8e7a51dba85dd23656baadb7e44238

Comment: 6е правило в вопросе гласит: "_В программе запрещено использовать любые встроенные в язык и библиотеки к нему функции сжатия и кодирования данных (Такие как: zip/unzip, base64)_"

Comment: Я ж не виноват, что символы ASCII в UTF-8 не отображаются :)

Comment: А в этом то и соль вопроса, что бы придумать такие функции самостоятельно :) (P.S. Кстати, у меня есть вариант с шрифтом занимающим 50 байт только печатными ascii символами, правда декодирование слишком сложно :) )

Comment: @Mike, убрал base64_decode().

Comment: У меня не получилось добиться правильного вывода от кода на 211 символов. Можете разместить тест на sandbox? И почему в строке 57 символов? Как это может работать? Должно быть 70.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, берете код для генерации, генерируете test.php и запускаете test.php после этого. Если есть редактор, который нормально редактирует файлы в однобайтных кодировках (пробовал MS WordPad) можете в нем править test.php.

Comment: @Visman Да, кстати, почему нет сандбоксовского (или ideone) примера на текущий вариант ?

Comment: Да, сгенерировал, открыл в PhpStorm в однобайтовой кодировке. Работает. 227 символов все же, а не 211 ))  http://take.ms/eWGEp

Comment: @Mike, наверное потому, что они в UTF-8 код принимают.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, подсчитывается тело функции, а у него длина 211 байтов.

Comment: @Mike Sandbox принимает код в UTF-8. echo(русские буквы работает) например. Проблема в том, что в этом ответе строка содержит символы 0-255, а однобайтовые символы Unicode это только 0-127. Именно это обстоятельство я учел в своем ответе, моя строка шрифта содержит только символы в диапазоне 0-127. Поэтому мой ответ работает в sandbox.

Comment: да, точно. Тогда согласен, 211. А в моем ответе 214, значит.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Уже локти кусаю, что не написал в правилах, что скрипт не должен содержать непечатных в UTF8 символов (включая, кстати, управляющие). Хотя я подумывал вообще запретить байты с установленным 8 битом, но подумал что слишком жестко

Comment: @Mike, так можно все возможности языков по запрещать :Р

Comment: @Visman Это не возможности языков, а кривой, не портабельный код. И что вы хотели, если задание в общем то не на вывод, а на укладывание кодированного шрифта в код :)

Comment: @Mike, это не `не портабельный код`, а ограничения накладываемые кодировкой UTF-8. Но однобайтные кодировки ни кто не отменял.

Comment: По мне так если код нельзя без потерь перенести на платформу с UTF-8, это как раз "не портабельный". Я то перед выкладыванием вопроса заморачивался, делал 7-битный, даже без управляющих символов. И кстати, зачем вам вообще 8й бит, если символы в шрифте из 7 точек. я вот считал 8й бит пробелом между символами и он очень удачно всегда 0 :)

Comment: @Mike, я взял ваш шрифт из вопроса, а в нем как раз символ занимает 8 бит.

Comment: @Visman Пробел после символа к нему в общем то не относится :) с другой стороны символ все равно гораздо удобнее кодировать как 8 бит, во первых что бы не вычислять сложные смещения, когда биты начнут сдвигаться, во вторых, что бы автоматом вывести тот самый пробел между символами. Просто у меня биты в байте идут задом наперед, поэтому 8й бит всегда пустой

Comment: грязный хак на минус 6 байт `for(;$l<7;) .... $a{$l++*10+$y}`, только вывод ошибок запретить в php.ini. Можно без грязи на -1 символ `for($l=-1;$l++<6;)`

Answer (score 7):

## Delphi, 407 символов

Запишу пока что, потом подумаю еще. На C/C++, конечно, короче будет, хотя и над этим еще надо подумать, как ужать.

```
program numbers;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses SysUtils, strUtils;

const a: array[0..6] of string = (
'1C083E3E407F3E7F3E3E',
'22184141424040424141',
'41280101424040044141',
'41083E3E427E7E083E3F',
'410840017F0141104101',
'22084041024141104141',
'1C3E7F3E023E3E103E3E');

const s = '1234567890';
var r,b: byte;
    c: char;
    x : word;
begin
    for r:=0 to 6 do begin
      for c in s do begin
        x := strToInt('$'+copy(a[r],1+StrToInt(c)*2,2));
        for b := 6 downto 0 do
          write(ifthen(x and (1 shl b)>=1, '#', ' '));
        write(' ');
      end;
      writeln;
    end;
end.
```

*зы: как длину то считаете*

Comment: Выбрасываете все незначащие пробелы и переводы кареток, `uses SysUtils, strUtils;` - так как это подключение страндартных библиотек, которое не учитывается. `const s = '1234567890';` т.к. оно нужно для тестирования. сохраняете в файл, смотрите размер. как то так

Comment: выкинул лишнее, однострочный вариант - 407. с Delphi XE7 вроде 0-индексные строки, там на 2 символа короче

Comment: Другой язык лучше отдельным ответом, иначе в таблице рейтинга строки другой не будет

Comment: @Mike ага, разделил, заодно добавил еще вариант с другой кодировкой

Answer (score 7):

## PHP, 214 символов и байт

```
function d($s){
    $c='>>@>>>"AAB@ABAAA(B@@AAA>>B~~>?A@AA"@AAAAA>>>>>>';
    for($l=0;$l<7;$l++){
        for($d=0;$d<strlen($s);$d++){
            for($j=1;$j<9;$j++){
                echo(decbin((ord($c{$l*10+$s{$d}})+128)<<1)){$j}?'#':' ';
            }
        }
        echo"\n";
    }
}

d('98765432101');
```

Тест http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/003b619c2dcc3f0ddff2c5b3c21a14b9be92c49c

В сжатом виде тело функции имеет длину 214 символов и байт:

```
function d($s){$c='>>@>>>"AAB@ABAAA(B@@AAA>>B~~>?A@AA"@AAAAA>>>>>>';for($l=0;$l<7;$l++){for($d=0;$d<strlen($s);$d++){for($j=1;$j<9;$j++){echo(decbin((ord($c{$l*10+$s{$d}})+128)<<1)){$j}?'#':' ';}}echo"\n";}}
```

В отличие от других вариантов на php, работает в UTF-8.

Comment: По ссылке на сандбокс нерабочий вариант

Comment: @rjhdby с чего это вы так решили?

Comment: вот картинка http://take.ms/23mwL

Comment: я прошел по ссылке и нажал "execute". https://ibb.co/ecEEdF

Comment: И я сделал то же самое. И прежде чем опубликовать сандбокс, я его, естественно, 10 раз проверил.

Comment: Ну вот как есть так и есть. Возможно дело в особенностях отображения непечатных символов браузером

Comment: Chrome последний под Windows - все ок

Comment: @rjhdby, уменьшите количество цифр для печати, их отображение не помещается в строку и переползает дальше.

Comment: @Visman ну вот совсем не похоже

Comment: @rjhdby какая просьба: если вы приходите смотреть сандбокс в браузере, который занимает 3% рынка, то хоть предупреждайте об этом, чтобы мы не теряли времени в догадках. Не работает sandbox в вашем Safari. А почему - не ко мне вопрос. В Chrome, IE, Edge, Firefox, Opera - все в порядке.

Comment: @KAGGDesign я 4 коммента выше о том и написал, что проблема в браузере скорее всего и вопросов никаких более нет. Извините, если недостаточно четко дал это понять. :)

Answer (score 7):

## Crystal 0.22, 250 байт

```rb
def foo(s)
7.times{|i|s.each_byte{|b|8.times{|j|print (1&[0x1C22414141221C,0x3E0808080A0C08,0x7F01013E40413E,0x3E41403E40413E,0x20207F21212101,0x3E41403F01017F,0x3E41413F01413E,0x404040810217F,0x3E41413E41413E,0x3E41407E41413E][b-48]>>8*i+j)>0?"#": " "}};puts}
end
foo("0123456789");
```

https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/24o0

Основано на коде https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/674586/253020

Comment: На Ruby чуть короче, не стал писать.

Вообще говоря, иные решения (Антона на Perl, или другие) также можно перевести на Ruby/Crystal, и будет более кратко. Но цели выиграть за счет синтаксиса нет.

Comment: У меня вопрос к жюри, почему нельзя string.to_i(16), например, когда во многих решениях используется тот же sprintf, который чутка дофига больше конвертирует?

Comment: sprintf используется для перевода системы счисления (как например decbin в php), но ни как не влияет на степень сжатия исходного шрифта, не облегчает задачу по укладыванию сырых бинарных данных в текстовую строку. Если to_i(16) это перевод из шестнадцеричной - то норм. На счет вашего предыдущего варианта, я спрашивал что это потому как не мог точно классифицировать ... и тут походу дыра в правилах, потому как по хорошему это то же перевод системы счисления, которое не запрещалось, я вроде как не планировал заставлять всех переводить СС делением и остатками :) ...

Comment: Блин, ну зачем вы это спросили, я же теперь буду весь день думать над сложнейшим философским вопросом, что такое base64 и чем оно отличается от функции перевода системы счисления с основанием 64 ... А что sprintf, в моей первой редакции вместо него было `map$c>>$_&1?'#':' ',(0..7)` что в общем то даже короче чем sprintf с последующей конвертацией 0/1 в знаки, хотя по образу применения sprintf сэкономил 2 байта

Comment: В общем сформулировали sprintf как функцию выводящую данные из внутреннего представления машины в человекочитаемый вид, а не переводящую систему счисления. Хотя все равно как то кривовато ...

Answer (score 6):

## Java, 596 символов

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "0123456789";
        String i[] = s.split("");
        int n[][] = {
            {
                9,
                8,
                3,
                3,
                3,
                8,
                9
            },
            {
                12,
                10,
                7,
                12,
                12,
                12,
                6
            },
            {
                6,
                3,
                15,
                6,
                4,
                4,
                0
            },
            {
                6,
                3,
                15,
                6,
                15,
                3,
                6
            },
            {
                4,
                2,
                2,
                2,
                0,
                14,
                14
            },
            {
                0,
                4,
                4,
                1,
                15,
                3,
                6
            },
            {
                6,
                3,
                4,
                1,
                3,
                3,
                6
            },
            {
                0,
                2,
                13,
                12,
                11,
                11,
                11
            },
            {
                6,
                3,
                3,
                6,
                3,
                3,
                6
            },
            {
                6,
                3,
                3,
                5,
                15,
                3,
                6
            }
        };
        String[] b = {
            "#######",
            "###### ",
            "#    # ",
            "#     #",
            "#      ",
            " ######",
            " ##### ",
            " # #   ",
            " #   # ",
            "  ###  ",
            "  ##   ",
            "  #    ",
            "   #   ",
            "    #  ",
            "     # ",
            "      #"
        };
        for (int m = 0; m < 7; m++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < i.length; k++) {
                System.out.print(b[n[Integer.parseInt(i[k])][m]] + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Краткий вариант:

```
public class Main {public static void main(String[] args){String s="0123456789";String i[]=s.split("");int n[][]={{9,8,3,3,3,8,9},{12,10,7,12,12,12,6},{6,3,15,6,4,4,0},{6,3,15,6,15,3,6},{4,2,2,2,0,14,14},{0,4,4,1,15,3,6},{6,3,4,1,3,3,6},{0,2,13,12,11,11,11},{6,3,3,6,3,3,6},{6,3,3,5,15,3,6}};String[] b={"#######","###### ","#    # ","#     #","#      "," ######"," ##### "," # #   "," #   # ","  ###  ","  ##   ","  #    ","   #   ","    #  ","     # ","      #"};for(int m=0; m<7;m++){for(int k=0;k<i.length;k++){System.out.print(b[n[Integer.parseInt(i[k])][m]]+" ");}System.out.print("\n");}}}
```

[проверка](http://ideone.com/47u4eL)

Answer (score 6):

## C#, <s>313</s> <s>305</s> <s>304</s> <s>302</s> <s>299</s> <s>281</s> <s>279</s> <s>278</s> <s>277</s> <s>276</s> <s>275</s> <s>261</s> <s>259</s> <s>258</s> <s>252</s> 250 байтов

```
void f(string s){
    for(int i=-1,j;++i<7;WriteLine())foreach(var c in s)for(Write(" "),j=0;j<7;)Write((new[]{-0x88F7EF9FCFA2,-0x1CB86CD9AB6,1056705L<<28,0,-0x790413A7D03D,0x102041,16449<<14,-0xE9EBC6CC0FBF,16385<<14,8193<<14}[c-48]+0xfa0c07d020be>>i*7+j++&1)>0?"#":" ");
}
```

ЗЫ. `using static System.Console;` - считаем как подключение стандартной библиотеки

В немного более читабельном виде:

```
using static System.Console;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {                
        ShowNumber("0123");
        ReadLine();
    }

    static void ShowNumber(string s)
    {
        for (int i = -1, j; ++i < 7; WriteLine())
            foreach (var c in s)
                for (Write(" "), j = 0; j < 7;)
                    Write((new[] {
                                    -0x88F7EF9FCFA2,
                                     -0x1CB86CD9AB6,
                                       1056705L<<28,
                                                  0,
                                    -0x790413A7D03D,
                                           0x102041,
                                          16449<<14,
                                    -0xE9EBC6CC0FBF,
                                          16385<<14,
                                           8193<<14
                                 }[c - 48] + 0xfa0c07d020be >> i * 7 + j++ & 1) > 0 ? "#" : " ");
    }
}
```

Перенос объявления массива внутрь `Write` позволил выиграть 7 байт
Перевод магических чисел в шестнадцатеричную систему позволил выиграть 8 байт
Перевод `'0'` в `48` позволил выиграть еще один байт
Чтение [этого](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2bxt6kc4(v=vs.110).aspx) позволило избавиться от пары скобок и выиграть 2 байта
Перенос вывода разделителей между цифрами в `Write` позволил уменьшить магические числа и выиграть 3 байта
Убрал из подсчета заголовок функции
Перенос `WriteLine()` внутрь заголовка `for()` позволил выкинуть пару скобок `{}` и выиграть 2 байта (подсмотрено в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/674586/218063) ответе)
Замена операции сравнения `==` на `<` дает еще байт
Вынос объявления переменных перед циклами позволил выиграть еще байт
Перенос инкремента `j++` в тело цикла позволил выиграть еще байт
Перенос инкремента `++i` в предусловие позволил выиграть еще байт
Вынос постоянного слагаемого позволяет выиграть невероятные 14 байт (возможно выбор другого слагаемого может улучшить результат еще на 1-2 байта, но лень выбирать)
Вынос вывода разделителя между цифрами в заголовок цикла позволил выиграть еще 2 байта
Рекомендация @Qwertiy даёт еще один байт
Формирование магических чисел с помощью сдвигов дает еще 6 байт
Удалил лишнюю пару скобок (не понятно откуда она взялась) - 2 байта

Comment: Есть идея преобразования `a ? ' ' : '#'` в `" #"[a]`, но из-за необходимости приведения `long` => `int` весь выигрыш аннулируется, может у кого будут идеи по этому поводу

Comment: а что нибудь типа `" #"[a%1]` не прокатит ? (если у вас остаток от деления %). И кстати `==0` обязательно ? может убрать его и поменять местами # с пробелом

Comment: @Mike, это `C#`, увы, здесь сильная типизация. long % long (int) даст long. А int/long в bool вообще не конвертится. В индексаторе `[здесь]` для массива определено только использование int.

Comment: [Я догнал)))](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/675771/178988)

Comment: @Qwertiy, поздно, этот ответ уже устарел )) Другой здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/675849/218063

Answer (score 5):

## C++, 283

```
uint64_t a[]={0x1C22414141221C,0x3E0808080A0C08,0x7F01013E40413E,0x3E41403E40413E,0x20207F21212101,0x3E41403F01017F,0x3E41413F01413E,0x404040810217F,0x3E41413E41413E,0x3E41407E41413E};for(int i=0;i<7;++i,printf("\n"))for(int c:s)for(int I=0;I<8;++I)putchar(1&a[c-48]>>8*i+I?'#':' ');
```

Читаемый код

```
void foo(std::string s)
{
    uint64_t a[]={0x1C22414141221C,0x3E0808080A0C08,0x7F01013E40413E,0x3E41403E40413E,0x20207F21212101,0x3E41403F01017F,0x3E41413F01413E,0x404040810217F,0x3E41413E41413E,0x3E41407E41413E};

    for(int i=0;i<7;++i,printf("\n"))
        for(int c:s)
            for(int I=0;I<8;++I)
                putchar(1&a[c-48]>>8*i+I?'#':' ');
}

int main() {
    foo("0123456789");
    return 0;
}
```

Проверка: https://ideone.com/gKYibz

Comment: В плюсах можно записать вместо `uint64_t a[]={1,2,3}; ... a[...]` такое: `{1,2,3}[...]`?

Answer (score 5):

## PHP7.0, 235 символов

Вариант со словарем как в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/674589/186083) ответе

```
<?php
function p($s) {
for($l=0;$l<7;++$l){foreach(str_split($s)as$y)printf('%8s',strtr(decbin([1,2,4,8,16,24,28,34,40,62,63,64,65,66,126,127][hexdec('6399bf9f9975ccdbcdccc800dbb2ccc399dee39ac3b0f0c4c073bc1cc4cc69f9199499'{$l*10+$y})]),'01',' #'));echo"\n";}
}
p('0123456789');
```

Тест http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/afde422cf8c2e3deca2e1adee9802570ead8189c

Comment: че то я лох, в моем ответе можно было не запихивать алфавиты в отдельную переменную, сэкономил бы 8шт :) а в этом ответе, можно было бы еще пару символов сэкономить, заменить `echo "\n";` как у меня на `?>\n\n<?`

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript, 726 cимволов, 757Кб)

```js
function p(s){
var d=[[7,'  ###',' #   #','#     #',2,2,1,0],[5,'  #',' ##','# #','  #',3,3,'f'],[7,' #####','#     #','      #',0,'#',4,'f'],[7,' #####','#     #','      #',0,2,1,0],[7,'#','#    #',1,1,'f','     #',5],[7,'f','#',1,'######','      #','#     #',' ##### '],[7,' #####','#     #','#','######',1,1,0],[7,'f','#    #','    #','   #','  #',4,4],[7,' #####','#     #',1,0,1,1,0],[7,' #####','#     #',1,' ######','      #',1,0]];for(var h=0;h<7;h++){var ps='';for(var c of s){var cn=parseInt(c);var cd=d[cn];var cm=cd[h+1];var dl=cd[0];if(typeof cm=='number'){cm=d[cn][cm+1]}if(cm.indexOf('f')+1){cm='';for(var j=0;j<dl;j++){cm+='#'}}var ml=cm.split('').length;if(ml<dl){for(var j=ml;j<dl;j++){cm+=' '}}ps+=cm+' '}console.log(ps)}}
p('0123456789')
```

Comment: `757Кб` слишком много.

Comment: @visman да я в курсе, не претендую на первое место. Просто когда увидел думал вообще не смогу написать)

Comment: Я про килобайты указанные у вас :) а не про число.

Answer (score 5):

## Perl, -132 байта (вне конкурса, использует функцию кодирования)

укороченный вариант решения от Anton Petrusevich

```
$_="0987654321";
for$l(0..6){say map{(unpack'(B8)*','>>@>>>"AAB@ABAAA(B@@AAA>>B~~>?A@AA"@AAAAA>>>>>>')[$l.$_]=~y/01/ #/r}/./g}
```

Использованы непечатные символы ASCII, поэтому копипаст отсюда работать не будет. На ideone можно увидеть [рабочий пример](http://ideone.com/K9CmPX). Пятая строка длиной 132 байта.

Comment: `unpack` слишком мощное средство распаковки строки и пожалуй попадает под ограничение п.6 условий "запрещено использование функций сжатия и _кодирования_ данных". Хотя достаточно красиво (если не считать не печатных символов, для избавления от которых люди тратят дополнительно по 4-6 байт)

Comment: @Mike если `unpaсk` нельзя, то буду требовать в стокгольмском арбитраже, чтоб `sprintf` тоже запретили ))

Comment: sprintf обсуждали в чате, пришли к выводу, что это средство вывода конкретного значения из внутреннего представления машины в человекочитаемый вид. ключ: "переводит одно значение". А unpack в том виде как используется тут преобразует строку кодов из системы счисления с основанием 256 в  массив бинарных данных, т.е. по факту делает то же что и base64, только круче, потому как у того основание СС 64

Comment: Т.е. если бы unpack использовался вместо sprintf для вывода одного значения - ok. но не для обработки массива целиком. И sprintf заменяется на `map$c>>$_&1?'#':' ',(0..7)` который не особо его длиннее. А вы найдите короткую замену unpack

Comment: @Mike ну тогда возвращаемся к `sprintf`
141 байт пятая строка [решения со sprintf] (http://ideone.com/dBeLlD)
Вариант Антона, только без перекодирования непечатных символов и с по другому упакованным шрифтом. Не посимвольно, а построчно.

Comment: Если вы видели нашу переписку с Антоном (хотя большинство моих комментов уже удалено), мы с ним сошлись во мнении, что код с непечатными символами некрасив, поэтому мы осознанно теряем драгоценные байты, но делаем весь шрифт печатным (он пошел своим методом, который чуть длиннее моего, но он решил не брать мой, что бы не плагиатить). Так что технически он может быть короче. Хотя ваше `$l.$_` это серьезное улучшение и главное, не очевидное, которое стоит показать. И в любом случае данный ваш вариант полностью проходит по всем правилам.

Comment: `$l.$_` можно в моём коде тоже применить, если шрифт перепаковать. Идея заменить `$l*10+$_` на `$l.$_` принадлежит "Someone Unknown" из телеграм-чата, так что я попробую у себя тоже.

Answer (score 5):

## Javascript ES6, <s>382</s> <s>309</s> <s>276</s> <s>271</s> <s>259</s> 258 символов

Входные данные в переменной s.

```
eval("[[56b=16c=124cd=128g=254cgcc],[68 48e=130ef=132defee],[e80a=2afdd8ee],[ebccfh=252hbc126],[ebdagae32ea],[68bde4ee32ee],[56cgc4cc32cc]]"[R='replace'](/\d+|\w(?!=)/g,'$&,')).map(x=>s[R](/./g,m=>(256+x[m]).toString(2)[R](/./g,b=>" #"[b]).slice(1))).join`
`
```

## Проверка

```js
t = s => eval("[[56b=16c=124cd=128g=254cgcc],[68 48e=130ef=132defee],[e80a=2afdd8ee],[ebccfh=252hbc126],[ebdagae32ea],[68bde4ee32ee],[56cgc4cc32cc]]"[R='replace'](/\d+|\w(?!=)/g,'$&,')).map(x=>s[R](/./g,m=>(256+x[m]).toString(2)[R](/./g,b=>" #"[b]).slice(1))).join`
`

document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input", function (e) {
  document.querySelector("pre").textContent = t(e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, ''));
})
```

```css
body { display:inline-block; }
input { position:sticky; left:8px; width:calc(100vw - 16px); box-sizing:border-box; }
```

```html
<input>
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 5):

## C#, <s>248</s> <s>194</s> <s>193</s> <s>188</s> <s>187</s> <s>177</s> 176 байтов

Другой подход с упаковкой цифр не в `long`-константы, а в строку с символами, т. е., по сути, в число в 128-ричной системе:

```
static void f(string s)
{
    for(int i=-5,j;++i<3;WriteLine())foreach(var c in s)for(j=0;j<8;)Write(" #"[("~r``k!`!``Ln++Kk+K+++t**Kkkz+++r``Kaar` +rk*!*+f+*Lrk+J++f++~`!`J``f``"[i*10+c-8]-6^100)>>j++&1]);
}
```

Использует все наработки из моего предыдущего ответа + задействована хотелка из комментария.

В более читабельной форме:

```
using static System.Console;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ShowNumber2("012345678");
        ReadLine();
    }

    static void ShowNumber2(string s)
    {
        for (int i = -5, j; ++i < 3; WriteLine())
            foreach (var c in s)
                for (j = 0; j < 8;)
                    Write(" #"[
                                  (
                                      "~r``k!`!``Ln++Kk+K+++t**Kkkz+++r``Kaar` +rk*!*+f+*Lrk+J++f++~`!`J``f``"
                                          [i * 10 + c - 8] - 6 ^ 100
                                  ) >> j++ & 1
                              ]);
}
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/xhiOgv

Невероятно, но факт - один маленький `XOR` позволяет выкинуть из строки кучу управляющих последовательностей и выиграть ~50 байт!
Рекомендация @Qwertiy даёт еще один байт
Замена `x^0b111...111` на `~x` приносит 5 байтов и третье место в рейтинге
Рекомендация @Mike дает еще один байт
Благодаря помощи @Mike по подбору значения для `XOR` удалось выиграть еще 10 байт
Еще одна хитрость приносит байт

Comment: Объявления переменных закинь в for - сэкономишь одну `;`

Comment: @Qwertiy, пройденный этап - посмотрите изменения в моем другом ответе - наоборот вынос их позволил избавиться от одного `int` и выиграть байт

Comment: `int i=-1,j;for(;` => `for(int i=-1,j;` - получается на символ меньше.

Comment: @Qwertiy, ах вот вы о чем! Good!

Comment: Есть идея сделать на основе 70-байтной строки словарь, там ведь всего 16 различных символов, но пока не понятно как добиться уменьшения кода...

Comment: `~` то же не нужна. Уберите ее и поменяйте местами пробел и #. Вы же фактически инвертируете биты, так что 0 вполне может означать #

Comment: @Mike, спасибо, применил. Будем думать еще

Comment: @Mike, хм, 181 байт по моим подсчетам, что короче чем у меня. Идею понял, в прошлом ответе мне было выгодно вынести вывод пробела между цифрами отдельно, по инерции перетащил его и сюда. Буду разбирать

Comment: @Mike, странное только значение `2^96` - это ведь просто `98`

Comment: Нет, приоритеты другие, сначала из кода символа вычитается 2, а потом инвертируются 2 старших бита

Comment: @Mike, хм, интересный тонкий момент какой, спасибо. А если не с 96 ксорить? Ну ладно, это я уже сам посмотрю

Comment: Придумал строку без кавычек и управляющих. `-6^100` выигрываем еще 4 символа

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby and Crystal -161b

Вне конкурса вариант Антона (+Майка), просто чтобы показать синтаксис Ruby и Crystal, тут у них совпало.

```rb
v="0987654321"
7.times{|l|puts v.chars.map{|c|("%08b"% (127&(80+"LRqqqRL8HX888nnq1npp/nq1n1qnprrr/22/pp.1qnnqp.qqn/r48@@@nqqnqqnnqqo1qn"[c.to_i*7+l].ord))).tr("01"," #")}.join}
```

http://ideone.com/XvoUPZ

Answer (score 4):

## PostrgeSQL (8.4+), 284 байта

```
select string_agg(translate((ascii(substr(s,c::int+l::int*10+1,1))-2#96)::bit(8)::text,'01',' #'),' ')
  from (values('~j``"!`!``Dz##$"#$###Jcc$""f###j``$  j`a#j"c!c#r#cDj"#d##r##~`!`d``r``')) B(s),
       regexp_split_to_table('0123456','') l,
       regexp_split_to_table('9876543210','') c
 group by l
 order by l
```

Число которое надо вывести задается в 4й строке. В [примере на sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/17310) пришлось заменить пробелы на подчеркивания, потому что там вывод на экран происходит в HTML (соседние пробелы подавляются), но разглядеть можно. На экране в pgAdmin (утилита из комплекта поставки postrgesql) выглядит замечательно.

Answer (score 4):

### F#, 496 байт

```
let p (s:string)=
    let f o v = String([|for i=(56-(o*8)) downto (56-(o*8)-7) do yield if (if i>32 then((v>>>30)&&&(1L<<<(i-31)))<>0L else(v&&&(1L <<< i-1))<>0L)then '#' else ' '|])
    printfn "%s"(List.fold(fun a e-> a+(Array.fold(fun b v->b+(f e ([0x38448282824438L;0x1030501010107CL;0x7C82027C8080FEL;0x7C82027C02827CL;0x80848484FE0404L;0xFE8080FC02827CL;0x7C8280FC82827CL;0xFE840810202020L;0x7C82827C82827CL;0x7C82827E02827CL].[(int v - int '0')])))""(s.ToCharArray()))+"\n")"" [0..6])
```

---

Тест: https://ideone.com/i0hTW0

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 675 символов

```
$a=['  ###      #     #####   #####  #       #######  #####  #######  #####   #####  ',' #   #    ##    #     # #     # #    #  #       #     # #    #  #     # #     # ','#     #  # #          #       # #    #  #       #           #   #     # #     # ','#     #    #     #####   #####  #    #  ######  ######     #     #####   ###### ','#     #    #    #             # #######       # #     #   #     #     #       # ',' #   #     #    #       #     #      #  #     # #     #   #     #     # #     # ','  ###    #####  #######  #####       #   #####   #####    #      #####   #####  '];for($l=0;$l<7;++$l){for($i=0;$i<strlen($s);++$i)echo substr($a[$l],$s{$i}*8,8);echo"\n";}
```

Он же читабельном виде

```
<?php
function p($s) {
    $a = ['  ###      #     #####   #####  #       #######  #####  #######  #####   #####  ',
          ' #   #    ##    #     # #     # #    #  #       #     # #    #  #     # #     # ',
          '#     #  # #          #       # #    #  #       #           #   #     # #     # ',
          '#     #    #     #####   #####  #    #  ######  ######     #     #####   ###### ',
          '#     #    #    #             # #######       # #     #   #     #     #       # ',
          ' #   #     #    #       #     #      #  #     # #     #   #     #     # #     # ',
          '  ###    #####  #######  #####       #   #####   #####    #      #####   #####  '];
    $n = strlen($s);
    for($l=0;$l<7;++$l){
        for($i=0;$i<$n;++$i){
            echo substr($a[$l],$s{$i}*8,8);
        }
        echo "\n";
    }
}

p('0123456789876543210');
```

Тест http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3dfa4d73057fab8a04c6f58656fde6ecd19c51db

Comment: Как бы подразумевалось, что шрифт не помешало бы как то ужать, что бы места меньше занимал ... Но конечно, на ваше усмотрение, условиям соответствует :)

Comment: @Mike, шрифт-то конечно можно ужать, да и сам код почистить от пробелов и лишних переменных, но надо глянуть, что другие предложат в качестве решения.

Comment: Ну вот я предложил что-то похожее для начала :)

Answer (score 3):

Второй вариант на PHP, с друго кодировкой алфавита

## PHP, 273 символа

читабельный вариант:

```
$s = "1234567890";
$n = [1,2,4,8,16,24,28,34,40,62,63,64,65,66,126,127];
$a = ['6399BF9F99','75CCDBBDCC','C800DBB2CC','C399DE9399','C3B0F0C4C0','73BC1CC4CC','69F9199499'];
foreach($a as $l){
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($s);$i++){
        for($b=6;$b>=0;$b--){
            echo $n[hexdec($l[$s[$i]])]&1<<$b?'#':' ';
        }
    ?> <?
    }
echo "\n";
}
```

Краткий вариант:

```
$n=[1,2,4,8,16,24,28,34,40,62,63,64,65,66,126,127];$a=['6399BF9F99','75CCDBBDCC','C800DBB2CC','C399DE9399','C3B0F0C4C0','73BC1CC4CC','69F9199499'];foreach($a as $l){for($i=0;$i<strlen($s);$i++){for($b=6;$b>=0;$b--)echo $n[hexdec($l[$s[$i]])]&1<<$b?'#':' ';?> <?}?>

<?}
```

Answer (score 2):

Аналог кода на Delphi из предыдущего ответа переписанный на php.

## PHP, 285 символов

читабельный вариант:

```
$s = "1234567890";
$a=['1C083E3E407F3E7F3E3E','22184141424040424141','41280101424040044141','41083E3E427E7E083E3F','410840017F0141104101','22084041024141104141','1C3E7F3E023E3E103E3E'];
foreach($a as $l){
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($s); $i++){
        for($b=6; $b>=0; $b--) echo hexdec(substr($l,$i*2,2))&1<<$b?'#':' ';
        ?> <?
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

*краткий вариант в 3 строки:*

```
foreach(['1C083E3E407F3E7F3E3E','22184141424040424141','41280101424040044141','41083E3E427E7E083E3F','410840017F0141104101','22084041024141104141','1C3E7F3E023E3E103E3E'] as $l){for($i=0;$i<strlen($s);$i++){for($b=6;$b>=0;$b--)echo hexdec(substr($l,$i*2,2))&1<<$b?'#':' ';?> <?}?>

<?}
```

Comment: у вас  тут - `strlen($s)` действительно `$s` ?

Comment: @TimurVI да, это входная строка. в коде просто отсутствовала

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 252 байта

Весь код:
http://ideone.com/SzOJCG

Только функция:

```
int i=0,j;for(;i<70;i+=10){foreach(var c in s)for(j=0;j<8;j++)Write(new BitArray(new[]{(int)"\x1\x4\x8\x10\x14\x18\x1e !8>?@AD|~\x7f\uc282"["JDKKARKRKKOFNNIANINNSEMMIAADNNSDKKILLCKQSDAMRMNBNMODANHNNBNNJPRKHKKBKK"[i+c-48]-65]})[j]?'#':' ');WriteLine();}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Kotlin, 233 <s>234</s> <s>243</s> <s>268</s>, зато без непечатных символов :)

```
(0..6).map{c->s.map{(BigInteger("cq7ntkqmgle8bf3logj0a8x7uwoe4u3x2dpfv5x5hvwz7z25fob8oanyd2cs7xt99qeaoj1bnj3jw1guzhbzknwgyi7cdz5",36).toString(2).replace('0','4').drop(c*70+it.toInt()*7-336).take(7)+"1").map{print(it-17)}};println()}
```

Развернуто

```
import java.math.BigInteger
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val s = "110123456789"

    (0..6).map{c->
               s.map{(BigInteger("cq7ntkqmgle8bf3logj0a8x7uwoe4u3x2dpfv5x5hvwz7z25fob8oanyd2cs7xt99qeaoj1bnj3jw1guzhbzknwgyi7cdz5",36)
                      .toString(2)
                      .replace('0','4')
                      .drop(c*70+it.toInt()*7-336)
                      .take(7)+"1"
                     )
                     .map{print(it-17)}
                    }
               println()
    }
}
```

Попробовать можно [тут](https://try.kotlinlang.org), просто скопировать туда целиком развернутый код

Answer (score 1):

## PHP,  465 символов

```
$a = "###";
$z = "   ";
$s = "0123456789";
$i = str_split($s);
$n = [[9, 8, 3, 3, 3, 8, 9], [12, 10, 7, 12, 12, 12, 6], [6, 3, 15, 6, 4, 4, 0], [6, 3, 15, 6, 15, 3, 6], [4, 2, 2, 2, 0, 14, 14], [0, 4, 4, 1, 15, 3, 6], [6, 3, 4, 1, 3, 3, 6], [0, 2, 13, 12, 11, 11, 11], [6, 3, 3, 6, 3, 3, 6], [6, 3, 3, 5, 15, 3, 6]];
$b = ["#$a$a", "$a$a ", "# $z# ", "#  $z#", "#$z$z", " $a$a", " ##$a ", " # #$z", " #$z# ", "  $a  ", "  ##$z", "  # $z", "$z#$z", " $z#  ", "  $z# ", "$z$z#"];

for ($m = 0; $m < 7; $m++)
    {
    for ($k = 0; $k < count($i); $k++)
        {
        echo $b[$n[$i[$k]][$m]] . " ";
        }

    echo "\n";
    }
```

Краткий вариант

```
$a="###";$z="   ";$s="0123456789";$i=str_split($s);$n=[[9,8,3,3,3,8,9],[12,10,7,12,12,12,6],[6,3,15,6,4,4,0],[6,3,15,6,15,3,6],[4,2,2,2,0,14,14],[0,4,4,1,15,3,6],[6,3,4,1,3,3,6],[0,2,13,12,11,11,11],[6,3,3,6,3,3,6],[6,3,3,5,15,3,6]];$b=["#$a$a","$a$a ","# $z# ","#  $z#","#$z$z"," $a$a"," ##$a "," # #$z"," #$z# ","  $a  ","  ##$z", "  # $z","$z#$z"," $z#  ","  $z# ","$z$z#"];for($m=0;$m<7;$m++){for($k=0;$k<count($i);$k++){echo $b[$n[$i[$k]][$m]]." ";}echo "\n";}
```

[Проверка](http://ideone.com/rSHzUB)

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, 244 байта (без учёта первых двух строк)

```
s=input()
from re import sub
for r in range(7):print(*(eval(sub('(.)'*2,r'+" "*0x\1+"#"*\2',hex(int('3BKFT57KVYH9NKP5RWAHYETF85SH2KMQ1BKLL2CVX0HPWX1W2WBGPNN1SHAZPXK7JS0JP0V493SO5PSD1JDSIOB1VMCY67RQ2N7X94FSBVDX9MV0UCUVVSK5GR0DHCG',36)))[15:])[int(d)*7+r*70:][:7]for d in s))
```

Comment: подключение стандартных библиотек не считается, так что `import re` то же вычитайте

Comment: @Mike, хм… а `from re import sub as b` учитывается?

Comment: Ну это будет уже перебор :) только подключение, а не переименование функций

Comment: @Mike `from re import sub` тем не менее считается за подключение?

Comment: Не знаю, надо в чате обсуждать. ладно, подключайте, я так понимаю вы таким образом сэкономите `re.` ? В других случаях надо будет конечно обсудить этот вопрос