# Как записать цифры ASCII графикой на Java?

Tags: java, графика, ascii

Как можно вывести строку из задаваемых пользователем произвольного набора цифр большим, символьным шрифтом? Должна быть возможность легко заменять шрифт.

Пример шрифта

```
  ___    __   ___    ____    _  _     _____     __    ______    ___     ___   
 / _ \  /_ | |__ \  |___ \  | || |   | ____|   / /   |____  |  / _ \   / _ \  
| | | |  | |    ) |   __) | | || |_  | |__    / /_       / /  | (_) | | (_) | 
| | | |  | |   / /   |__ <  |__   _| |___ \  | '_ \     / /    > _ <   \__, | 
| |_| |  | |  / /_   ___) |    | |    ___) | | (_) |   / /    | (_) |    / /  
 \___/   |_| |____| |____/     |_|   |____/   \___/   /_/      \___/    /_/
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/674415/184217

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/674859/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d1%8b-ascii-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0-java#comment984306_674865

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Код-гольф: Увеличиваем цифры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/674415/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%84-%d0%a3%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d1%8b)

Comment: Не путайте гольф с вопросом. Там задание на краткость, тут на заменяемость отображения цифр.

Comment: @Crantisz В оригинальном вопросе этого не было указано https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/674859/2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хорошей идеей будет создать класс цифры. В нём будет храниться полное представление цифры, то есть массив строк, такой, что если его вывести на экран, получится изображение цифры.

Если вы хотите использовать моноширинный шрифт, а цифры имеют разную ширину, то одним из решений может быть добавление в представление цифры нескольких столбиков пробелов, так что итоговая ширина всех цифр станет одинаковой. Ниже приведён код для моноширинного шрифта, а также функция `createDigits` для удобного создания массива цифр из описания шрифта. Обратите внимание, что в описании шрифта должны присутствовать добавочные столбики пробелов, так, например, между цифрами `1` и `2` два столбика пробелов, а не один ­— из-за того, что собственная ширина цифры `1` на единицу меньше ширины всех остальных цифр.

Если вы хотите использовать НЕ моноширинный шрифт, то вам нужно написать собственный вариант функции `createDigits`, который будет искать столбики пробелов, и на основе них создавать объекты класса цифры.

```
static class Digit {
    String[] lines;

    public Digit(String... lines) {
        this.lines = lines;
    }

    /**
     * функция для удобного создания массива Digit[] из описания шрифта
     * работает только с моноширинными шрифтами, 
     * причём моноширинность описания шрифта (то есть аргумента `lines`) должен гарантировать код, вызывающий функцию
     *
     * @param lines описание шрифта в виде строк с большими цифрами 0-9, цифры разделены пробелом
     * @return массив длины 10
     */
    public static Digit[] createDigits(String... lines) {
        int height = lines.length;
        int width = (lines[0].length() - 9 /* десять цифр => девять пробелов */) / 10;
        return IntStream
                .range(0, 10)  // Stream из цифр 0-9
                .mapToObj(digit ->
                        new Digit(Stream
                                .of(lines)
                                // цифры в line идут следующим образом:
                                // `width` символов цифры `0`, пробел,
                                // `width` символов цифры `1`, пробел,
                                // ...
                                .map(line -> line.substring(digit * (width + 1), (digit + 1) * (width + 1) - 1))
                                .toArray(String[]::new))
                ).toArray(Digit[]::new);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Digit[] digits = Digit.createDigits(
            "  ###      #     #####   #####  #       #######  #####  #######  #####   ##### ",
            " #   #    ##    #     # #     # #    #  #       #     # #    #  #     # #     #",
            "#     #  # #          #       # #    #  #       #           #   #     # #     #",
            "#     #    #     #####   #####  #    #  ######  ######     #     #####   ######",
            "#     #    #    #             # #######       # #     #   #     #     #       #",
            " #   #     #    #       #     #      #  #     # #     #   #     #     # #     #",
            "  ###    #####  #######  #####       #   #####   #####    #      #####   ##### "
    );
    int height = digits[0].lines.length;

    // число 5781, для удобства уже разбитое на цифры
    int[] number = {5, 7, 8, 1};
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int digit : number) {
            System.out.print(digits[digit].lines[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Демонстрация работы на [ideone](http://ideone.com/9QrPkH).

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Ну, тогда вам поможет [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/674559/227016).

Comment: Я бы хотел иметь возможность редактировать шрифт. Как это сделать?

Comment: @miustrox, я думал, вы хотели, чтобы мы код для соревнования написали, а оказывается ваш вопрос не так сильно связан с тем соревнованием.

Comment: Одно другому не мешает. В конкурсе нет ограничений на максимальный размер кода.

Comment: Ну, отправлять длинное решение на конкурс не слишком интересно. Вообще я не очень понимаю, зачем вы такой вопрос задали...

Comment: Хотелось увидеть адекватное решение данной задачи.

Comment: Только Вы не учли, что цифры, вообще говоря разной ширины. Так между единицей и любой другой цифрой будет два пробела, в то время от других цифр отступ в один пробел. И это ещё повезло что узкая цифра захватила только пробелы. Шрифт как в вопросе полностью поломается.

Comment: @Sergey, это хорошее замечание, написал, что работает только с моноширинным шрифтом.