# Реализация шкалы времени в символьно-графическом представлении

Tags: java, время, switch

К примеру, на вход подаются 2 числа, на выход должны получить следующее:

```
####  ####       ####  ####
#  #  #  #   #   #  #  #  #
#  #  #  #       #  #  #  #
#  #  #  #   #   #  #  #  #
####  ####       ####  ####
```

Если делать перебором, через switch, то это слишком долго и не производительно. Может быть, можно через массивы реализовать?

```
public class Program{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 1;
        String out;
        switch(a+":"+b){
            case "0:0":
                out = "#### ####   #### ####\n#  # #  # # #  # #  #\n#  # #  #   #  # #  #\n#  # #  # # #  # #  #\n#### ####   #### ####";
                System.out.println(out);
                break;
            case "0:1":
                out = "#### ####   #### ###\n#  # #  # # #  #   #\n#  # #  #   #  #   #\n#  # #  # # #  #   #\n#### ####   #### ####";
                System.out.println(out);
                break;

            case "":
                out = "";
                System.out.println(out);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: что за два числа?

Comment: В `switch-case` можно сделать вывод одной цифры, а дальше... ну Вы поняли.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Как записать цифры ASCII графикой на Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/674859/227016)

Comment: а зачем вы каждые варианты часов проверяете в switch? достаточно только цифру единственную и сделать это лучше через enum!

Comment: @diraria но лучше это сделать в enum

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как записать цифры ASCII графикой на Java?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/674859/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d1%8b-ascii-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0-java)

Comment: @zRrr там корявый ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Можно определить цифры через enum:

```
 public enum TypeNumber {
    ZeroType("//реализация числа в стринге", 0),
    OneType("//реализация числа в стринге", 1),
    TwoType("//реализация числа в стринге", 2),
    ThreeType("//реализация числа в стринге", 3),
    FourType("//реализация числа в стринге", 4),
    FiveType("//реализация числа в стринге", 5),
    SixType("//реализация числа в стринге", 6),
    SevenType("//реализация числа в стринге", 7),
    EightType("//реализация числа в стринге", 8),
    NineType("//реализация числа в стринге", 9);
    String value;
    int num;

    TypeNumber(String str, int number) {
        value = str;
        num = number;
    }

    public static String getValueNumber(int num) {
    for (TypeNumber type : TypeNumber.values()) {
        if (type.num == num) {
            return type.value;
        }
    }
    return null;
   }
}
```

Чтобы получить строку числа просто используете: `TypeNumber.getValueNumber(номер нужной цифры)`

Comment: Не можно, а нужно. Такого рода задачи на enum и делаются!