# ASCII вывод в консоли

Tags: c#, массивы, консоль, вывод, ascii

Pебята, всем  привет. Данo задание с ASCII. Есть .txt  документ в нем хрониться вот это

```
L = 4
H = 5
T = E
 #  ##   ## ##  ### ###  ## # # ###  ## # # #   # # ###  #  ##   #  ##   ## ### # # # # # # # # # # ### ### 
# # # # #   # # #   #   #   # #  #    # # # #   ### # # # # # # # # # # #    #  # # # # # # # # # #   #   # 
### ##  #   # # ##  ##  # # ###  #    # ##  #   ### # # # # ##  # # ##   #   #  # # # # ###  #   #   #   ## 
# # # # #   # # #   #   # # # #  #  # # # # #   # # # # # # #    ## # #   #  #  # # # # ### # #  #  #       
# # ##   ## ##  ### #    ## # # ###  #  # # ### # # # #  #  #     # # # ##   #  ###  #  # # # #  #  ###  #
```

Как видите это ALPHABET. L это длинна , H это высота а  T , это  что я хочу вывести. В результате должно получиться это :

```
### 
#   
##  
#   
###
```

Конечно,T может менятсяб и это нужно вывести в консоль. Вот мой стартовый код

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ascii
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] fileContent = File.ReadAllLines("gg.txt");

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", fileContent)); \\прост проверочка))
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Л и Н не меняються,только Т. Есть какие-нибудь идеи?Без понятия как стартануть. П.С Русский знаю плохо сорри за грамматикую))

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Код-гольф: Увеличиваем цифры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/674415/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%84-%d0%a3%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d1%8b)

Answer (score 4):

```
string[] patterns =
{
    "#  ", " # ", "  #",
    "## ", "# #", " ##",
    "###"
};

Dictionary<char, string[]> letters = new Dictionary<char, string[]>()
{
    { 'A', new [] { patterns[1], patterns[4], patterns[6], patterns[4], patterns[4] } },
    { 'B', new [] { patterns[3], patterns[4], patterns[3], patterns[4], patterns[3] } },
    { 'C', new [] { patterns[5], patterns[0], patterns[0], patterns[0], patterns[5] } },
    { 'D', new [] { patterns[3], patterns[4], patterns[4], patterns[4], patterns[3] } },
    { 'E', new [] { patterns[6], patterns[0], patterns[3], patterns[0], patterns[6] } },
    { 'F', new [] { patterns[6], patterns[0], patterns[3], patterns[0], patterns[0] } },
    { 'G', new [] { patterns[5], patterns[0], patterns[4], patterns[4], patterns[5] } },
    { 'H', new [] { patterns[4], patterns[4], patterns[6], patterns[4], patterns[4] } },
    { 'I', new [] { patterns[6], patterns[1], patterns[1], patterns[1], patterns[6] } },
    { 'J', new [] { patterns[5], patterns[2], patterns[2], patterns[4], patterns[1] } },
    { 'K', new [] { patterns[4], patterns[4], patterns[3], patterns[4], patterns[4] } },
    { 'L', new [] { patterns[0], patterns[0], patterns[0], patterns[0], patterns[6] } },
    { 'M', new [] { patterns[4], patterns[6], patterns[6], patterns[4], patterns[4] } },
    { 'N', new [] { patterns[6], patterns[4], patterns[4], patterns[4], patterns[4] } },
    { 'O', new [] { patterns[1], patterns[4], patterns[4], patterns[4], patterns[1] } },
    { 'P', new [] { patterns[3], patterns[4], patterns[3], patterns[0], patterns[0] } },
    { 'Q', new [] { patterns[1], patterns[4], patterns[4], patterns[5], patterns[2] } },
    { 'R', new [] { patterns[3], patterns[4], patterns[3], patterns[4], patterns[4] } },
    { 'S', new [] { patterns[5], patterns[0], patterns[1], patterns[2], patterns[3] } },
    { 'T', new [] { patterns[6], patterns[1], patterns[1], patterns[1], patterns[1] } },
    { 'U', new [] { patterns[4], patterns[4], patterns[4], patterns[4], patterns[6] } },
    { 'V', new [] { patterns[4], patterns[4], patterns[4], patterns[4], patterns[1] } },
    { 'W', new [] { patterns[4], patterns[4], patterns[6], patterns[6], patterns[4] } },
    { 'X', new [] { patterns[4], patterns[4], patterns[1], patterns[4], patterns[4] } },
    { 'Y', new [] { patterns[4], patterns[4], patterns[1], patterns[1], patterns[1] } },
    { 'Z', new [] { patterns[6], patterns[2], patterns[1], patterns[0], patterns[6] } }
};

while (true)
{
    Console.Write("Символ: ");
    string s = Console.ReadLine();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
    {
        if (s == "exit")
        {
            break;
        }

        char[] chars = s.ToUpper().ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", chars.Select(ch => letters[ch][i]).ToArray()));
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
}
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если считывать алфавит из файла:

```
const int width = 4;

const string alphabet = @"C:\Users\admin\Documents\in.txt";

List<string> lines = new List<string>();

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(alphabet, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)))
{
    string line = sr.ReadLine();

    while (line != null)
    {
        lines.Add(line);
        line = sr.ReadLine();
    }
}

while (true)
{
    Console.Write("Символ: ");
    ConsoleKeyInfo ch = Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine();

    int num = ch.KeyChar - 'A';


    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", lines.Select(l => l.Substring(width * num, 3)).ToArray()));
    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("NOPE!");
    }
}
```