# Как напечатать буквы в консоле через звездочки?

Tags: java, python

Есть 3 буквы на входе "А В В" Нужно вывести в консоль?
Так должна выглядеть буква

```
   *          
 * * *   
*     *
```

Если можно какой-то универсальный способ решения и для других букв алфавита. Дайте совет в какую сторону двигаться?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [ASCII вывод в консоли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787194/ascii-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю смотреть надо в сторону ASCII Art.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int width = 100;
    int height = 30;

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
    g.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 24));

    Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g;
    graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    graphics.drawString("JAVA", 10, 20);

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) 
            sb.append(image.getRGB(x, y) == -16777216 ? " " : "*");

        if (sb.toString().trim().isEmpty())
            continue;
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

Примеры [тут](https://www.mkyong.com/java/ascii-art-java-example/), [тут](https://www.baeldung.com/ascii-art-in-java) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098972/ascii-art-java)

Answer (score 1):

Раньше это называлось битовый шрифты. Идея в том, что вы создаете массив из, например, N 16ричных чисел и потом где бит = 1 - выводите звездочку, где 0 - пробел.
То есть буквы "I" массив в двоичном представлении будет выглядеть вот так:

```
00000000
00011000
00011000
00011000
00011000
00011000
00011000
00000000
```

Далее просто выбираете такие обращаетесь к таким буквам как, например, через dict и рисуете их.
Основная проблема для вас будет в том, что так как буквы имеют высоту, вам надо использовать библиотеку, которая умеет позиционировать указатель в нужную точку экрана. Для python можно использовать ncurses, для Java надо поискать. Я именно так делал для себя в игре - но там я выводил текст в графике.

Answer (score 1):

Для питона есть библиотека pyfiglet, количество символов для выводимой буквы 3х5. Пример:

```
> from pyfiglet import figlet_format
> 
> print(figlet_format('A B B', font='3x5'))


 #      ##      ##  
# #     # #     # # 
###     ##      ##  
# #     # #     # # 
# #     ##      ##
```