# Гольф-код. Палиндромная перестановка

Tags: алгоритм, строки, любой-язык, соревнование, палиндромы

**Условие**

Палиндром - это слово, фраза или последовательность символов, которая читается одинаково как с начала, так и с конца (например, "ротор" или "мадам"). Вам нужно написать программу, которая определит, можно ли из заданной строки сделать палиндром путем перестановки ее символов.

**Входные данные**

Строка, состоящая из букв латинского алфавита (от `a` до `z`).

**Выходные данные**

Вывести строку `'YES'`, если можно переставить символы так, чтобы получить палиндром, и `'NO'` в противном случае.

**Контрольный пример**

```
Вход: "aab"
Выход: "YES" (можно сделать "aba")

Вход: "abc"
Выход: "NO"

Вход: "racecar"
Выход: "YES" (это уже палиндром)

Вход: "aaa"
Выход: "YES"
```

**Критерий оценивания**

Любой язык программирования.

В соревновании победит самое короткое по символам решение (пробелы и переносы - тоже символы).

Ответ победителя будет отмечен верным. Ответ автора вопроса не будет фигурировать при выборе победителя.

**Срок соревнования - 7 дней, конец 10.10.2023 в 8:00 по МСК**

---

P.S.

Просьба указывать язык в заголовке ответа и количество символов программы через запятую.

Таблица лидеров ([код формы результатов взял отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/892196/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B5/896212#896212))

```js
execute("ru.stackoverflow.com", "1543735");
```

```css
.cssload-container,.cssload-cube{width:97px;height:97px;transform-style:preserve-3d}.cssload-container,.cssload-cube,.cssload-half1,.cssload-half2{transform-style:preserve-3d}.cssload-container{position:relative;margin:23px 84px;perspective:292px}.cssload-cube{animation:cube 11.5s forwards infinite;transform-origin:center 49px}.cssload-half1,.cssload-s1{top:0;transform-origin:50% 100%}.cssload-half1{height:39px;position:absolute;animation:half-fold 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-side{width:19px;height:19px;background:#ddd;position:absolute}.cssload-s1{left:39px;animation:s1ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s2,.cssload-s3,.cssload-s4{left:39px;transform-origin:50% 0}.cssload-s2{top:19px;animation:s2ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s3{top:39px;animation:s3ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s4{top:58px;animation:s4ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s5{left:19px;top:19px;transform-origin:100% 50%;animation:s5ani 11.5s forwards infinite}.cssload-s6{left:58px;top:39px;transform-origin:0 50%;animation:s6ani 11.5s forwards infinite}@keyframes cube{0%,30%{transform:rotateX(0)}40%{transform:rotateX(45deg) rotateY(0) rotate(45deg)}60%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotateY(0) rotate(45deg)}65%,70%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotate(45deg) rotate(180deg)}75%,80%{transform:rotateX(60deg) rotate(45deg) rotate(1turn)}90%{transform:rotateX(0) rotate(0) rotate(0)}}@keyframes s1ani{0%{opacity:1;transform:translateY(0);background:#ddd}40%{transform:rotateX(0);background:#ddd}50%{transform:rotateX(-90deg);background:#ddd}90%{transform:rotateX(-90deg)}}@keyframes s2ani{0%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}10%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{background:#ddd}45%,80%{background:#b4b4b4}65%{opacity:1;background:#b4b4b4}90%{opacity:1}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s3ani{0%,10%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}20%,90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{background:#ddd}45%{background:#969696}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s4ani{0%,20%{opacity:0;transform:rotateX(-179deg)}10%,to{opacity:0}30%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(0)}40%{transform:rotateX(0);background:#ddd}50%{transform:rotateX(90deg);background:#b4b4b4}80%{background:#b4b4b4}90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateX(90deg)}}@keyframes s5ani{0%,10%{opacity:0;transform:rotateY(-179deg)}20%{opacity:1;background:#ddd;transform:rotateY(0)}40%{transform:rotateY(0)}50%{transform:rotateY(90deg)}55%{background:#ddd}60%{background:#c8c8c8}90%{transform:rotateY(90deg);opacity:1}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes s6ani{0%,20%{opacity:0;transform:rotateY(179deg)}30%{opacity:1;transform:rotateY(0)}40%{transform:rotateY(0)}50%{transform:rotateY(-90deg);background:#ddd}60%,80%{background:#c8c8c8}90%{opacity:1;transform:rotateY(-90deg)}to{opacity:0}}@keyframes half-fold{0%,50%{transform:rotateX(0)}60%,90%{transform:rotateX(-90deg)}}
```

```html
<script src="https://mayorovp.github.io/codegolf/table-8c505e68f1349e4c69e7.js"></script>
<div class=cssload-container><div class=cssload-cube><div class=cssload-half1><div class="cssload-side cssload-s1"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s2"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s5"></div></div><div class=cssload-half2><div class="cssload-side cssload-s3"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s4"></div><div class="cssload-side cssload-s6"></div></div></div></div>
```

---

### Результаты и объявление победителей:

В начале хочется выразить огромные благодарности всем участникам данного соревнования за боевой дух и креативность! Представленные решения вызывают восторг и восхищение.

Особая благодарность [@Зонтик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/532877/%D0%97%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA) за вовлеченность в модерацию и редактуру ответов.

**1 место:** [@Stanislav Volodarskiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/416121/stanislav-volodarskiy), [Ruby](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1544186/470029), **56 символов!**

**2 место:** [@Чёткая Четырка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/468004/%D0%A7%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0), [Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1544426/470029), **57 символов!**

**3 место:** [@Алексей Р](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/519463/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%A0), [Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1543737/470029), **63 символа!**

Всем спасибо за участие!

Comment: *количество символов минифицированной функции через запятую* — так это должна быть функция или полная программа? Для С, например — со всеми `#include` или просто функция? Нет, я участвовать не собираюсь (раз уж общий счет для любого языка), но сама постановка...

Comment: @Harry исправил

Comment: Python создать переменную, просто ее написать, в javaScript потребуется ключевое слово let(с учетом пробела +4 символа). Чтение ввода пользователя в js `prompt`, в c++(если не ошибаюсь) `cin`. Выовод в c++ `cout`, в python `print`, в js `console.log`... т.е. есть языки, которые по символам проигрывают заранее... названия методов это отдельная история.

Comment: @SwaD Да, тоже думал о том, что это прям плохо, но в любом случае готов к критике и предложениям, при том, что основа "любого языка" должна остаться как есть

Comment: @SwaD А в общем-то, если пользователь намерен победить, то он будет использовать язык в котором будет минимум по длине методов, в таком случае он будет привязан к определённым языкам. В другом случае сетоваю на тех, кто участвует не ради победы, а ради того, чтобы показать "как можно" и сделать это интересно, получив свои голоса и репутацию как бонус. Данное действие в принципе познавательный импакт имеет.

Comment: является ли палиндромом пустая строка?

Comment: А получение строки от пользователя  + вывод на экран результата входит в количество символов?

Comment: @Grundy пустая строка не соответствует входным данным, так как не состоит из букв латинского алфавита (`a` до `z`), при этом одиночный символ - палиндром.

Comment: @Зонтик входит. Предполагается, что программу можно запустить на языке как есть, следовательно, необходимо в том числе организовать все необходимые импорты/инклуды

Comment: Раньше в таких соревнованиях требовалось написать ф-ю, остальная обвязка не считалась. Необходимость описания ввода-вывода сразу исключает всевозможные экзотические варианты типа sql (да, были и такие! https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/675325/218063) и прочих

Comment: Считающим байты: не учитывайте перевод строки после последней строки. Его можно удалить из файла (`head -c-1 temp.py > temp_.py`), код продолжит нормально работать.

Comment: @Зонтик о "победах" я писал выше в ответ на сообщение SwaD

Comment: Что  удивительно, больше десятка ответов, и только четыре плюса на вопросе. Это как? Соревнуемся, а автору вопроса никакой благодарности?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy да конкурс получился дебильным на самом деле, ответов было бы миллион, если бы я принял решение о том, что можно упаковать всё в функцию, но с следующим конкурсом поправлю моментов и сделаю увлекательней. Тем не менее я восхищаюсь большей части ответов здесь.

Comment: @Acinit, конкурс, очевидно, получился!

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy видимо народ смутил критерий оценки. Кстати, уже 10 плюсов :)

Comment: @Acinit а вот я тут подумал, и понял: конкурс хороший. Да, пайтон по любому ведёт, но я и так на победу не претендую. Зато сколько всего интересного: и сам решаешь задачки, и смотришь на другие решения, и узнаёшь про языки, про которые не знал... А ещё на конкурс пришёл бывший модератор с хешкода, который в последнее время редко публикует сообщения. Вряд ли такой участник пришёл бы на скучное :)

Comment: @Зонтик >Python по любому ведёт. Не сказал бы, по таблице выигрывает решение на Ruby (я в шоке)

Comment: @Acinit ещё php может выиграть. Где-то уже был вариант (видимо удалили), но он был без ввода строки. А так было 47 символов.

Comment: @Acinit, а из каких символов кроме a-z состоит пустая строка?

Comment: @SwaD, в js вполне можно создать переменную простым присваиванием.

Comment: @Qwertiy никаких, она же пустая :) Пробелы и переносы не входят в диапазон от `a` до `z`

Comment: Вопрос, делать еще соревнования, думаю, риторический :)

Comment: @Acinit конечно=)))

Comment: @Acinit, вот именно потому что она пустая - она соответствует условиям.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Ruby, 56

```rb
b=1024
gets.chars{|c|b^=1<<c.ord}
puts b&b-1>0?:NO: :YES
```

Целая переменная `b` хранит чётность количества символов. Например для `'a'` чётность хранится в девяносто седьмом бите, для `'z'` в сто двадцать втором бите.

Начальное значение *1024* нужно так как `gets` возвращает строку с переводом строки. Переводу строки соответствует десятый бит (*1024*). Он выставлен заранее, перевод строки в конце строки его снимает.

В конце проверяется что в `b` установлен только один бит. Выражение `b & (b - 1)` стирает младший бит числа. Если число обнулилось, этот бит был единственным.

Comment: [Работает!](https://replit.com/@Acinit/RubyTest23)

Comment: Прям заявочка на победу

Comment: Поздравляю вас с победой!)

Answer (score 21):

## Python, 60

```py
b=0
for c in input():b^=1<<ord(c)
print('YNEOS'[b&b-1>0::2])
```

Целая переменная `b` хранит чётность количества символов. Например для `'a'` чётность хранится в девяносто седьмом бите, для `'z'` в сто двадцать втором бите.

В конце проверяется что в `b` установлен только один бит. Выражение `b & (b - 1)` стирает младший бит числа. Если число обнулилось, этот бит был единственным.

Константы `'YES'` и `'NO'` смешаны в одну строку. Первая на чётных позициях, вторая на нечётных.

Answer (score 15):

### Python, 57

Думал много дней, наконец додумался) Работает так же, как и многие (с проверкой количества одинаковых символов в строке на чётность)

```
a={0}
for i in input():a^={i}
print('YNEOS'[len(a)>2::2])
```

---

Подробный разбор кода:

1. Первой строчкой мы создаём множество `a`
2. Идём по всем символам строки:

   Если символ есть в множестве `a`, удаляем его оттуда, а если нет - добавляем
3. Печатаем `YES` если количество элементов в множестве меньше или равно 1, иначе печатаем `NO`

---

Труднее всего понять последнюю строчку. Объясняю. Если длина массива равна 1, то есть два варианта:

- В строке изначально был 1 символ;
- Остался один непарный символ в строке, который можно поставить в середину и всё равно получится палиндром.

Оба этих варианта нам подходят, печатаем `YES`.
А если в строке 0 символов - все были парными, то есть это тоже нам подходят, также печатаем `YES`.

### P.S. СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ ЗА СОКРАЩЕНИЕ КОДА @StanislavVolodarskiy. Этот код рулит среди питоновских только благодаря ему:)

Comment: Но главная идея (идея с множеством) ваша собственная! Заслуженное лидерство!

Answer (score 12):

### Python, 63

Алгоритм - подсчет количества непарных символов

```py
s=input()
print(("NO","YES")[sum(s.count(c)%2 for c in{*s})<2])
```

Comment: `set(s) -> {*s}`

Comment: @user207200 спасибо, применил. -2 символа :)

Answer (score 12):

## C, 66

```c
b;main(c){while(c=getchar()-10)b^=1<<c-87;puts(b&b-1?"NO":"YES");}
```

Это полная программа, которую `gcc temp.c` превращает в работоспособный исполнимый модуль. При компиляции выдаётся шесть предупреждений, но ни одной ошибки.

Ниже тот же код, но не такой плотный.

Целая переменная `b` хранит чётность количества символов. Например для `'a'` чётность хранится в нулевом бите, для `'z'` в двадцать пятом бите.

В конце проверяется что в `b` установлен только один бит. Выражение `b & (b - 1)` стирает младший бит числа. Если число обнулилось, этот бит был единственным.

```c
#include <stdio.h> 

int main() {
    int b = 0;
    int c;
    while (c = getchar() - '\n') {
        b ^= 1 << (c - ('a' - '\n'));
    }
    puts((b & b - 1) ? "NO" : "YES");
}
```

Answer (score 11):

### C#, 70

- Использую Linq, который в пустом проекте .NET 7 подключен по умолчанию, просто создайте проект с включенным Top-Level Statements
- Группирую все буквы, и если количество групп с нечетным числом букв > 1, то это не палиндром.

Ввод передается аргументом запуска

```cs
Console.Write(args[0].GroupBy(x=>x).Sum(g=>g.Count()%2)>1?"NO":"YES");
```

Comment: `args[0]`  - схитрил, другие ребята по честному из stdin читают.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov не все, кому короче консоль читать, читают консоль

Answer (score 10):

### Python, 170

```
from collections import Counter
s = input()
counts = Counter(s)
odd_count = sum(1 for count in counts.values() if count % 2 != 0)
print("YES" if odd_count <= 1 else "NO")
```

Comment: Начну первым комментировать...
https://ideone.com/RxlM9q

Comment: @Harry правильно подметили, правильность важна, в данном случае данный ответ не может быть принят и не будет фигурировать в выборе победителя, потому что он неправильный

Comment: и в любом случае не будет, потому что автор ответа = автор вопроса, ы)

Comment: @Harry а у нас вообше-то ideone недоступна...

Comment: @чистов_n процитирую оттуда содержимое, там задан код из неправильного решения и примером `ааа`, где результат выдачи равен `'NO'`

Comment: @Acinit тогда кому недоступен ideone, вот ссылка на replit: https://replit.com/@nikola-chistov/acinitanswer#main.py

Comment: @чистов_n ну хоть бы комментариев к реплиту добавил, а тож никто не поймёт, что нужно вводить `aaa`

Comment: @Acinit добавил.

Comment: @чистов_n И что? У нас прошлой зимой бывало, было недоступно электричество, например — вас это сильно волновало? Вобщем, есть всякие vpn, прокси и иже с ними...

Answer (score 10):

### JavaScript, 66

## JUST FOR FUN

#### Решаем задачу на регулярках :)

Изи, просто делаем скучную замену, 66 символов.
Спасибо @Cerbrus - сократил на 7 символов.

```js
g=t=>[...t].sort().join``.replace(/(.)\1/g,'').length<2?'YES':'NO'

console.log(g('aab'))
console.log(g('abc'))
console.log(g('racecar'))
console.log(g('aaa'))
```

### Монорегулярка, это уже веселее, но 103 символа

Большое регулярное выражение, ищет символы, вошедшие нечётное количество раз:

```js
alert([...prompt().matchAll(/(.)(?<!\1.+)(?=(((.(?<!\1))*\1){2})*(.(?<!\1))*$)/g)].length<2?"YES":"NO")
```

Comment: Ввел ``ssd`` и вышло ``YES`` так и должно быть?

Comment: @YaMus да. `ssd` -> `sds`

Comment: сорян не прочитал задание до конца))

Comment: 63:  `g=t=>[...t].sort().join\`\`.repl........`

Answer (score 8):

### Python, 92

#### Решение с `Counter`!

```py
from collections import *
print(["NO","YES"][sum(i%2 for i in Counter(input()).values())<2])
```

UPD: Вот если надо ссылка на replit: https://replit.com/@nikola-chistov/myfisrtcodegolf#main.py

UPD2: Спасибо **@Acinit** за советы по укорочению.

Comment: замените `count` на один символ, например, `c`

Comment: а если еще `from collections import Counter as x`, то можно `x(s).values()`

Comment: @Acinit я даже не думал о таком сокращении :)

Comment: `if` не нужен для `sum`: `sum(i%2!=0 for i in Counter(input()).values())`

Comment: @CrazyElf только получается на один символ длиннее.

Comment: Хм, не могу понять, как выкидывание 1 и if и перенос выражения в другое место может удлинить код ) Если это так, то это магия какая-то ))

Comment: @CrazyElf можно оставить просто `i%2`

Comment: @Danis Да, точно, я торможу что-то )

Comment: пробел перед `for` не нужен. `i%2 for ...` аналогичен `i%2for ...`

Comment: Я ещё сократил код. Я использовал другие решения и ваши советы, уже 92 символа, вначале было 124!

Answer (score 8):

### Haskell, 62

Brute force: составляем все перестановки и проверяем есть ли среди них палиндром:

```
p(s)=if any(\x->reverse x==x)$permutations s then"YES"else"NO"
```

https://ideone.com/nV67QU

### Haskell, 66

Чуть более длинный вариант, но без брутфорса, идея из соседних ответов:

```
r[]="YES";r(a)="NO";p(s)=r.tail.filter odd.map length.group$sort s
```

https://ideone.com/YeNNSO

Comment: брутфорс палиндрома, просто вау!

Comment: А так можно? У меня штук 40 лишних символов в решении на F# из-за ввода-вывода. Можно не вводить, и не выводить, как здесь?

Comment: @MarkShevchenko нет, нельзя, подсчёт символов здесь неверный

Comment: @MarkShevchenko, раньше в таких соревнованиях требовалось написать функцию только. Пусть будет вне конкурса, не проблема

Answer (score 8):

### JavaScript, 78

```
f=([a,b,...c])=>a?a==b?f(c):1+f([b,...c]):0;g=a=>f([...a].sort())>1?'NO':'YES'
```

Демонстрация еще одной идеи: рекурсивная ф-я f, которая

- возвращает 0 для пустой строки (условие выхода из рекурсии)
- делит строку на первые 2 символа a, b и оставшийся хвост с

  - если a = b, то возвращает f(c)
  - иначе 1+f([b,...c])

```js
f=([a,b,...c])=>a?a==b?f(c):1+f([b,...c]):0;g=a=>f([...a].sort())>1?'NO':'YES'

console.log(g('aab'))
console.log(g('abc'))
console.log(g('racecar'))
console.log(g('aaa'))
```

Answer (score 8):

### Oracle, 159 <s>176</s>

```
select decode(nvl(sum(1),1),1,'YES','NO')from(select''from(select''s from dual)connect by rownum<=length(s)group by substr(s,rownum,1)having mod(count(1),2)=1)
```

Вне конкурса, т. к. нет "стандартного ввода-вывода" ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Реализована та же идея с подсчетом непарных символов:

```sql
select
  decode(
    nvl(sum(1), 1), -- 5. sum возвращает NULL если в подзапросе нет строк, поэтому меняем NULL на 1
    1, -- 6. здесь как раз обрабатываются случаи с одгним непарным символом и нулем (NULL заменили на 1 в п 5)
    'YES',
    'NO'
  )
from (
  select
    ''
  from (
    select 'racecar' s from dual -- 1. входная строка
  )
  connect by rownum <= length(s) -- 2. рекурсивный запрос для разворачивания строки посимвольно
  group by substr(s, rownum, 1) -- 3. группируем символы
  having mod(count(1), 2) = 1 -- 4. и берем только непарные
)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/68b32/6869/0

Comment: а что если хранимой функцией написать на `pl/sql`? Тогда и ввод есть и вывод.

Comment: @Acinit, ну тогда это уже другой язык, как по мне :)

Comment: Интересная идея использовать oracle :)

Answer (score 6):

## Java, 149

```java
interface G{static void main(String[]a)throws Exception{int b=0,c;for(;(c=System.in.read()-96)>0;)b^=1<<c;System.out.println((b&b-1)>0?"NO":"YES");}}
```

Ниже тот же код, но не такой плотный.

Целая переменная `b` хранит чётность количества символов. Например для `'a'` чётность хранится в первом бите, для `'z'` в двадцать шестом бите.

В конце проверяется что в `b` установлен только один бит. Выражение `b & (b - 1)` стирает младший бит числа. Если число обнулилось, этот бит был единственным.

```java
interface G {
    static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
        int b = 0;
        for (int c; (c = System.in.read() - 96) > 0; )
            b ^= 1 << c;
        System.out.println((b & b - 1) > 0 ? "NO" : "YES");
    }
}
```

Comment: `interface` позволяет не писать `public` перед `main`. "Use interface instead of class" ([Tips for golfing in Java](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java)).

Comment: Можно написать просто `throws Exception`, а не выкидывать конкретно `java.io.IOException`.

Comment: @Зонтик, спасибо! Поправил.

Comment: Можно ещё два отрезать, если использовать `.print()` вместо `.println()`

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov, строку все же перевести надо.

Comment: В условии ничего про перевод нет. Написано "вывести" и `print()` выведет

Answer (score 6):

### RUST, 263

```
use std::io::{self, Read};fn main(){let mut input = String::new();io::stdin().read_to_string(&mut input).unwrap();let mut b = 0;for c in input.chars().filter(|&c| c != '\n') {b ^= 1 << (c as u8 - b'a');}if b & (b - 1) != 0 {println!("NO");}else{println!("YES");}}
```

```
use std::io::{self, Read};
fn main() {
    let mut input = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_to_string(&mut input).unwrap();
    let mut b = 0;
    for c in input.chars().filter(|&c| c != '\n') {
        b ^= 1 << (c as u8 - b'a');
    }
    if b & (b - 1) != 0 {
        println!("NO");
    } else {
        println!("YES");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

### C, 623

понятно, что не будет лидером, но это забавно

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){int o_ed5791501b27396303ad4d84f62e05c3=(0x0000000000000000 + 0x0000000000000200 + 0x0000000000000800 - 0x0000000000000A00);int o_2502a808b536a16317ab10c437e81bc0;while ((o_2502a808b536a16317ab10c437e81bc0 = getchar()) != '\n'){o_ed5791501b27396303ad4d84f62e05c3 ^= (0x0000000000000002 + 0x0000000000000201 + 0x0000000000000801 - 0x0000000000000A03) << (o_2502a808b536a16317ab10c437e81bc0 - 'a');};puts((o_ed5791501b27396303ad4d84f62e05c3 & o_ed5791501b27396303ad4d84f62e05c3 - (0x0000000000000002 + 0x0000000000000201 + 0x0000000000000801 - 0x0000000000000A03)) ? "\x4E""O" : "\x59""E\123");};
```

Comment: Просто МЕГАкод)

Comment: [Он еще к тому же и реально работает!](https://replit.com/@Acinit/TestPal)

Comment: Не понял, а имена переменных несут смысл? Нельзя из сократить?

Comment: Это же просто обфускация https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1543860. В чем смысл и что тут забавного?

Comment: @user207200 забава написать сам обфускатор

Comment: Какое отношение к конкурсу?

Comment: @user207200 такое, что вообще "не ради победы, а ради участия", такое участие очень даже приветствуется

Comment: @Acinit приветствуется повторение чужого кода в ответах с другими именами переменных?

Comment: @user207200 процитируйте существующий ответ, пожалуйста

Comment: @Acinit дал же ссылку в комментарии.

Comment: @user207200 ну банально могу сказать, что в первом примере отсутствует явное объявление типов, например, первый пример проверяет является ли `b` степень двойки, а здесь используется `XOR` как `^`

Comment: @Acinit просто посмотрите на развернутую версию кода автора оригинального ответа.

Comment: @user207200, если ты способен взять код автора и сократить его, таким образом, выставив его впереди кода конкурента, то я не вижу проблем. Обратный случай, когда код подвергается обфускации, при этом являясь решением поставленной задачи, просто является комичным моментом и не создаёт никакой конкуренции другим пользователям.

Comment: @user207200 для всего остального существует [справка по вопросам-соревнованиям](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/code-golf).

Comment: @Acinit видимо не дотягиваю до осознания комичности

Answer (score 6):

## RUBY, <s>110</s> 90

```
b = 0
while (c = STDIN.getc) != "\n"
  b ^= 1 << (c.ord - 'a'.ord)
end
puts (b & (b - 1)).zero? ? "YES" : "NO"
```

upd 90

```
b=0
while(c=STDIN.getc)!="\n" 
  b^=1<<(c.ord-'a'.ord)
end
puts (b&(b-1)).zero?? "YES":"NO"
```

Comment: [Работает!](https://replit.com/@Acinit/RubyTest)

Comment: В Руби неограниченные целые. `- 'a'.ord` можно убрать.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy кстати согласен. Ну тут в любом случае до 60 не дотянет, но символов до 90-100 наверное ещё скинуть можно

Comment: Не согласен. У Руби компактный синтаксис. Она может выиграть.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy 
b=0 while(c=STDIN.getc)!="\n" b^=1<<(c-'a')end puts(b&(b-1)).zero? ? "YES":"NO"

79 cимволов, меньше не смог

Answer (score 6):

### ADA, 383

```
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   b : Integer := 0;
   c : Character;
begin
   loop
      Ada.Text_IO.Get(c);
      exit when c = Character'Val(Character'Pos('\n'));
      b := b xor (1 << (Character'Pos(c) - Character'Pos('a')));
   end loop;
   
   if (b and (b - 1)) /= 0 then
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("NO");
   else
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line("YES");
   end if;
end Main;
```

Answer (score 6):

### Perl, 77

```
my $b;while(my $c=ord(getc())-10){$b^=1<<($c-87);}print $b&($b-1)?"NO":"YES";
```

Comment: [Работает!](https://replit.com/@Acinit/PerlTest)

Answer (score 6):

## Lua, 82

```lua
s=io.read()repeat s,c=s:gsub('(.)(.-)%1','%2')until c<1 print(#s<2 and'YES'or'NO')
```

Удаляем (через regex) по 2 одинаковых символа пока удаляется, потом смотрим длину остатка.

Comment: [Работает!](https://replit.com/@Acinit/luatest)

Answer (score 5):

### F#, 141

```
printf (if System.Console.ReadLine()|>Seq.countBy id|>Seq.choose(snd>>fun c->if c%2=1 then Some c else None)|>Seq.length<2 then"yes"else"no")
```

Comment: Так как мы говорим о полноценной программе, добавьте в начало `open System` https://onecompiler.com/fsharp/3zpjeu6w5

Comment: @Acinit, я проверил, программа запускается в таком виде. `open System` не нужен, потому что доступ к `Console` у меня по полному пути `System.Console`.

Answer (score 5):

### C#, 250

```cs
string PalindromCheck(string inStr)
{
    int solo = 0;
    string ignoreList = "";
    foreach (char c in inStr)
    {
        if (ignoreList.Count(f => f == c) == 0 && inStr.Count(f => f == c) % 2 != 0)
            solo++;
        ignoreList += c;
        if (solo > 1)
            return "NO";
    }
    return "YES";                
}
```

Comment: функция `Count` принадлежит `.net`, следовательно должны быть соответствующие объявления, подсчёт символов неправильный

Comment: А как же объявление класса? Или в c# можно программу без класса как-то запустить (но почему-то в хелловорде класс объявляется)?

Comment: `Или в c# можно программу без класса` - можно @Зонтик

Answer (score 5):

### LISP, 249 <s>330</s>

```
(defun c ()
  (let ((s (read-line)))
    (let* ((counts (loop for c across s
                         count c into char-counts
                         maximize char-counts))
           (odd-count (count-if (lambda (count) (oddp count)) counts))
           (result (if (< odd-count 2) "YES" "NO")))
      (format t result))))

(c)
```

upd 249

```
(defun c ()
  (let* ((b 0)
         (c (read-char)))
    (loop while (not (char= c #\Newline)) do
      (setq b (logxor b (ash 1 (- (char-code c) (char-code #\a)))))
    (if (logand b (- b 1))
        (format t "NO")
        (format t "YES"))))
(c)
```

Comment: Впервые узнаю про существование [LISP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF), познавательно!

Comment: @Acinit у нас на ruSO оказывается даже метка [tag:lisp] есть.

Answer (score 5):

### Rust, 174 <s>176</s>

```rust
fn main(){let mut s=String::new();let _=std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut s);let mut b=0u128;for c in s.chars(){b^=1<<(c as u32)}println!("{}",if b&(b-1)==0{"YES"}else{"NO"});}
```

Компилируется без варнингов. За основу взял код на C.

UPDATE: Нашёл два лишних пробела.

Answer (score 4):

## Java, 270

В моём ответе два решения.

Код в обоих один и тот же, просто в одном все переменные названы односимвольно и всё записано в 1 строку.

Идея в том, что в строке-палиндроме может быть только один неповторяющийся символ. А если в строке чётное количество символов, то вообще ни одного.

Собственно код:

1. Нечитаемый, 270 символов.

```java
interface I{static void main(String[]a){String s=new java.util.Scanner(System.in).next();int e=0;String r="YES";for(int i=0; i<s.length();i++){char c=s.charAt(i);if(!s.matches(".*"+c+".*"+c+".*")){++e;r=((e>1)||(e>0&&s.length()%2==0))?"NO":"YES";}}System.out.print(r);}}
```

2. Читаемый, 585 символов.

```java
interface I {
    static void main(String[] args){
        String string = new java.util.Scanner(System.in).next();
        int repeatCharacters = 0;
        String result = "YES";
        for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++){
            char currentCharakter = string.charAt(i);
            if(!string.matches(".*" + currentCharakter  + ".*" + currentCharakter  + ".*")){
                ++repeatCharacters;
                result = ((repeatCharacters > 1) || (repeatCharacters > 0 && string.length() % 2 == 0))? "NO" : "YES";
            } 
        }
        System.out.print(result);
    }
}
```

Вывод (добавил цикл `while`, чтобы одним запуском кода продемонстрировать все тесты):

[image: скриншот вывода]

Answer (score 4):

## Java, 177

```java
interface I{static void main(String[]s){System.out.print(new java.util.Scanner(System.in).next().chars().sorted().reduce(0,(a,b)->(a&0xFF)==b?a>>8:(a<<8)|b)>>8==0?"YES":"NO");}}
```

Отформатированная версия

```java
interface I {
    static void main(String[] s) {
        System.out.print(
            new java.util.Scanner(System.in)
            .next()
            .chars()
            .sorted()
            .reduce(0, (a, b) -> (a & 0xFF) == b ? a >> 8 : (a << 8) | b)
            >> 8 == 0 ? "YES" : "NO");
    }
}
```

Comment: Хорошее решение. А если ещё и вместо сканера использовать `s`, то длина получится почти такая же, как у решения на Java у Stanislav Volodarskiy.

Comment: @Byb Тут всё на сортированности списка построено, если вместо строки читать посимвольно, то работать не будет.

Answer (score 3):

### Java, 281

Не в погоне за минимизацией числа символов, но просто ещё не видел тут решения с использованием Java Stream API, поэтому решил написать своё.

```java
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

interface I {
    static void main(String[] a) {
        System.out.print(
                new java.util.Scanner(System.in).next().chars().boxed()
                        .collect(groupingBy(c -> c, counting()))
                        .values().stream().filter(v -> v % 2 != 0).count() > 1 ? "NO" : "YES"
        );
    }
}
```

Особенно интересно в сравнении с ответом от *aepot*: вроде я тут ничего лишнего в стримах не делал, но, как видно, с использованием C# LINQ данная задача решается заметно короче.

Comment: Хм. На "aab" выводит "NO".

Comment: Точно? А у меня выводит "YES"

Comment: Извиняюсь, ошибка. Случайно место 'a' другую клавишу нажал.

Comment: Кстати, можно просто print использовать. Будет минимизация символов без извращений.

Comment: Но если записать код в одну строку, то вы можете претендовать на победу :)

Comment: Насчёт `print` - да, согласен, поправлю. Насчёт победы - это вряд ли, учитывая ответы по 60 символов) А в одну строку я не сделал просто чтобы читаемо было, да и это не сильно уменьшит число символов

Comment: Тут вот кстати интересной минимизацией оказался статический импорт методов класса `Collectors`. Если не импортировать статические методы, то в любом случае надо будет импортировать сам класс `Collectors`, а его методы вызывать через точку после имени класса. Или не импортировать, а писать полное имя, но это было бы проделано дважды. Так что в итоге статические импорт оба эти варианта побеждает.

Comment: Можно сделать 2 варианта: в одну строку и читаемый (и это всё в одном ответе). Про количество символов - очень сильно уменьшит. Ведь тут считается каждый пробел. А один отступ - 4 пробела...

Answer (score 3):

## Python, 67

[tio.run](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v9jWgCstv0ghWSEzD4gKSks0NK2K42wNbWwy80o0knWMzTS5CopAbHU/f/XMNIViNY1iXUPN1JziVPVI12B1zf//ixKTU5MTiwA)

```
s=0
for c in input():s^=1<<int(c,36)
print('NO'if s&(s-1)else'YES')
```

Answer (score 2):

## VBscript, 267

[vbscript](/questions/tagged/vbscript)

В моём ответе два решения.

Код в обоих похожий. Различия такие:

- В одном (в нечитаемом) все переменные названы односимвольно и всё записано в меньшее количество строк.
- Во втором (читаемом) добавлена просьба ввести число, а не просто пустое диалоговое окно + добавлены иконки (для красоты).

Идея в том, что в строке-палиндроме может быть только один неповторяющийся символ. А если в строке чётное количество символов, то вообще ни одного.

Собственно код:

1. Нечитаемый, 267 символов

```vbs
s=inputbox(""):dim a():For i=1to len(s):redim preserve a(i):a(i)=right(left(s,i),1):next:For each c in a:r=0:for i=1to UBound(a)
if a(i)=c then:r=r+1:end if:next:if r=1 then
l=l+1
if(l>1)or((l>0)and(len(s)mod 2=0))then
msgbox"NO":WScript.Quit
end if
end if:next:msgbox"YES"
```

2. Читаемый, 569 символов.

```vbs
str = inputbox("Введите строку:")
dim array()

For i = 1 to len(str) 
    redim preserve array(i)
    array(i) = right(left(str, i), 1)
next 

For each currentCharakter in array
    retreatCurrentCharakter = 0
    for i = 1 to UBound(array)
        if array(i) = currentCharakter then retreatCurrentCharakter = retreatCurrentCharakter + 1
    next
    
    if retreatCurrentCharakter = 1 then 
        repeatCharacters = repeatCharacters + 1
        if(repeatCharacters > 1) or ((repeatCharacters > 0) and (len(str) mod 2 = 0)) then
            msgbox"NO", 16 
            WScript.Quit
        end if
    end if
next

msgbox"YES", 64
```

Запуск читаемого варианта (ибо он красивей: с просьбой ввода строки и с иконками в окнах):

[image: вводим "aab"] [image: результат: "YES"]

[image: вводим "abc"] [image: результат: "NO"]

[image: вводим "aaa"] [image: результат: "YES"]

**P.S**: если у вас ОС windows, то вы можете сами запустить скрипт у себя на компьютере. Для этого создайте файл с расширением `.vbs`, cкопируйте код (лучше читаемый) и щёлкните по файлику два раза.

Comment: У меня олдскулы свело

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 113

```
import functools as f
print('YNEOS'[len(f.reduce(lambda a,b:a[:-1]if a[-1:]==b else a+b,sorted(input()),))>1::2])
```

Бладорность Станиславу за YNEOS хак!

Answer (score 2):

## Kotlin, 135

```
fun main(){print(if(readLine()!!.chars().sorted().reduce(0, {a,b->if(a and 0xFF==b)a.shr(8)else a.shl(8)+b}) shr 8==0)"YES" else "NO")}
```

Отформатированная версия

```
fun main() {
 print(
  if(readLine()!!.chars().sorted().reduce(0, {
    a,b->if(a and 0xFF==b)a.shr(8)else a.shl(8)+b
  }) shr 8==0) "YES" else "NO")
}
```

В Котлине нет привычных `& | << >>` для битовых операций (`&` и `|` там вообще булевские), поэтому приходится использовать `and` <s>`or`</s> `+` и `shl/shr`

Что интересно, в некоторых случаях инфиксная форма `x shl y` короче, чем `x.shl(y)`, а в других наоборот: `a.shr(8)else` короче, чем `(a shr 8)else`

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, 81

```
s=>eval(Object.values([...s].reduce((r,c)=>(r[c]^=1,r),{})).join`+`)<2?'YES':'NO'
```

Проверка:

```js
f=s=>eval(Object.values([...s].reduce((r,c)=>(r[c]^=1,r),{})).join`+`)<2?'YES':'NO'

for (var s of ["aab", "abc", "racecar", "aaa"]) {
  console.log(s, f(s))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, 87

```
s=>s.replace(/(.)((?=.*\1)|(?<=^(((?!\1).)*\1((?!\1).)*\1)*))/g,'').length<2?'YES':'NO'
```

```js
f=s=>s.replace(/(.)((?=.*\1)|(?<=^(((?!\1).)*\1((?!\1).)*\1)*))/g,'').length<2?'YES':'NO'

for (var s of ["aab", "abc", "racecar", "aaa", 'aaaa']) {
  console.log(s, f(s))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 341

```
def can_be_palindrome(s):
    letter_count = {}
    
    for letter in s:
        if letter in letter_count:
            letter_count[letter] += 1
        else:
            letter_count[letter] = 1

    odd_count = 0
    for count in letter_count.values():
        if count % 2 != 0:
            odd_count += 1

    if odd_count > 1:
        return "NO"
    else:
        return "YES"

input_str = input("Введите строку: ").strip()

result = can_be_palindrome(input_str)
print(result)
```

Answer (score -3):

### Assembly, 537

```
section .data
    msg db "Введите строку: ",0
    len equ $ - msg

section .bss
    input resb 255
    is_palindrome_msg resb 1

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, msg
    mov edx, len
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, input
    mov edx, 255
    int 0x80

    mov esi, input

    mov edi, esi
    add edi, eax
    dec edi

    mov byte [is_palindrome_msg], 1

check_palindrome:
    cmp byte [esi], byte [edi]
    jne not_palindrome

    inc esi
    dec edi

    cmp esi, edi
    jae is_palindrome

    jmp check_palindrome

not_palindrome:
    mov byte [is_palindrome_msg], 0

is_palindrome:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, is_palindrome_msg
    mov edx, 1
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80
```

Comment: Можете приложить пример работы в онлайн компиляторе? а то выдаёт `main.asm:48: error: label 'is_palindrome' inconsistently redefined`

Comment: а теперь `main.asm:34: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands`

Comment: mov cl, byte [is_palindrome_msg] ; Загрузить байт из is_palindrome_msg в cl

Comment: @Acinit это почти наверняка ChatGPT писал, этот код никто не запускал, отсюда и ошибки. Мне бот выдал почти такой же код. Недаром автор не оставил ни инструкций для сборки, не подсказок как это проверить, просто запостил голый код и всё.

Comment: @aepot похоже на то, осуждаю такое участие

Comment: @Acinit нахаляву пофармить плюсиков, почему бы и нет, кто-то же голосует за такие попытки. Соседний ответ на питоне из той же оперы, почти наверняка.

Comment: @aepot может тогда снести этот ответ?

Comment: @Зонтик формально я не могу ничего явно не нарушающее правила сносить, даже если очень хочется.

Comment: @aepot вроде же нарушает. В [прошлый раз](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12327/532877) аналогичного юзера забанили на неделю, а пост в конкурсном вопросе снесли.